# Extract filename and extension in Bash

Tags: bash, string, filenames

I want to get the filename (without extension) and the extension separately.

The best solution I found so far is:

```
NAME=`echo "$FILE" | cut -d'.' -f1`
EXTENSION=`echo "$FILE" | cut -d'.' -f2`
```

This is wrong because it doesn't work if the file name contains multiple `.` characters. If, let's say, I have `a.b.js`, it will consider `a` and `b.js`, instead of `a.b` and `js`.

It can be easily done in Python with

```
file, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
```

but I'd prefer not to fire up a Python interpreter just for this, if possible.

Any better ideas?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538504/uses-for-this-bash-filename-extraction-technique) explains this bash technique and several other related ones.

Comment: When applying the great answers below, do not simply paste in your variable like I show here **Wrong:** `extension="{$filename##*.}"` like I did for a while! Move the `$` outside the curlys: **Right:** `extension="${filename##*.}"`

Comment: This is clearly a non-trivial problem and for me it is hard to tell if the answers below are completely correct. It's amazing this is not a built in operation in (ba)sh (answers seem to implement the function using pattern matching). I decided to use Python's `os.path.splitext` as above instead...

Comment: As *extension* have to represent *nature* of a file, there is a *magic* command which check file to divine his nature and offert *standard extension*. see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17513633/1765658)

Comment: The question is problematic in the first place because.. From the perspective of the OS and unix file-systems in general, there is no such thing as a file extension. Using a "." to separate parts is a *human convention*, that only works as long as humans agree to follow it. For example, with the 'tar' program, it could have been decided to name output files with a "tar." prefix instead of a ".tar" suffix -- Giving "tar.somedir" instead of "somedir.tar". There is no "general, always works" solution because of this--you have to write code that matches your specific needs and expected filenames.

Comment: @C. M. 's comment is the best answer! In my case, all files had the same prefix (input.*) and I just wanted the extension so I could change the prefix (like rename but I didn't have that available). So I did this: `for f in input.*; do ext=$(echo $f | cut -c 7-); mv $f "output.$ext"; done`

Comment: @PeterGibson bad approach... now you opened a python instance and used pattern matching inside of it instead of just using pattern matching in the shell



@C.M. there is no such thing as "no such thing as a file extension". everyone knows what a file extension is and is already agreed upon by everyone. the only difference in *nix systems is that a file's type is given by the shebang `#!` inside the file if it exists. otherwise, it's given by the extension of that file if it exists. if neither exist then it defaults to `application/octet-stream` mime type.

Comment: What is the extension of the file `xyzzy.tar.gz`? Or `plugh.cfg.saved`? In other words, are you treating extension as a simple technical issue or a semantic one?

Comment: Um, the question as written reads like a cheap advert for Python. [Perl](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/perl-cookbook/1565922433/ch09s11.html) can do this, as can [Raku](https://docs.raku.org/language). In fact, Raku's [basename](https://docs.raku.org/routine/basename.html) page shows correct handling of both Windows/Unix filenames, and Raku's [extension](https://docs.raku.org/routine/extension) page shows how to handle up to 5-part extensions.

Answer (score 4410, accepted):

First, get file name without the path:

```
filename=$(basename -- "$fullfile")
extension="${filename##*.}"
filename="${filename%.*}"
```

Alternatively, you can focus on the last '/' of the path instead of the '.' which should work even if you have unpredictable file extensions:

```
filename="${fullfile##*/}"
```

You may want to check the documentation :

- On the web at section "[3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)"
- In the bash manpage at section called "Parameter Expansion"

Comment: Check out http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion for the full feature set.

Comment: Add some quotes to "$fullfile", or you'll risk breaking the filename.

Comment: Heck, you could even write filename="${fullfile##*/}" and avoid calling an extra `basename`

Comment: This "solution" does not work if the file does not have an extension -- instead, the whole file name is output, which is quite bad considering that files without extensions are omnipresent.

Comment: Fix for dealing with file names without extension: `extension=$([[ "$filename" = *.* ]] && echo ".${filename##*.}" || echo '')`. Note that if an extension _is_ present, it will be returned including the initial `.`, e.g., `.txt`.

Comment: Note the following about this solution:
 - For file names without extension, `$extension` returns _the file name_ rather than `""`.
 - `$extension` does not include the initial `"."`.
 - `$filename` will be `""`, if the input file name _starts with_ `"."` and contains no further `"."` characters (e.g., `.bash_profile`).

Comment: I've sometimes wished that `basename` had an option to remove an arbitrary extension. `basename foo.txt .txt` prints `foo`, but it can't strip the `.txt` unless you tell it what the suffix is. (Yes, it's easy enough to do with other facilities, but `"${filename%.*}"`isn't exactly easy to remember.)

Comment: @mklement0 : `.bash_profile` is a filename without a base in my sense. it is composed of just an extension. maybe that sounds weird, but *Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules*.

Comment: @v.oddou: Fair enough, it certainly simplifies the solution greatly (cf. the madness of my answer). However, it may not be what people expect (I didn't), so I thought it worth pointing out - initial-period-to-mark-hidden-files and period-as-extension-separator are competing concepts.

Comment: @mklement0 : Yes and I'd like a definite definition as well. Everybody should agree on this one, I think its important too. I just happen to vote for initial-periods having to be interpreted as extension separators, because it removes a special case. But that's just my personal vote. I think we should check how boost::filesystem, python and MS Win32 SplitPath... parses this kind of files to get our answer. And if they all agree, accept that as convention.

Comment: @v.oddou: Results: Python, Ruby, node.js, and Perl make the exception (treat `.` at the beginning special); by contrast, the Boost C++ library does not (and neither does .NET, but I don't think that matters, given that it was designed for Windows).

Comment: What is the reason for  the `--` in `filename=$(basename -- "$fullfile")` From my local tests, it seems to work just as well without it but am I missing something?

Comment: Alternatively, one could add `function rootname(){ echo "${1%.*}"; }` to their .bashrc

Comment: It won't work for files which have multiple dots in their names. This one fails `echo ${cmake-3.16.4.tar.gz##*.}`

Comment: This solution worked for me but you have to be careful if a) the name contains other dots and b) if `$fullfile` has a pattern (which will not expand because of the quotes). Removing the quotes seems to make it work fine in those cases: `touch okapiFiltersForOmegaT-1.8-1.40.0.jar && jarfile="okapiFiltersForOmegaT*.jar" &&  filename=$(basename -- $jarfile) && extension="${filename##*.}" && filename="${filename%.*}"`. That gives me the expected `okapiFiltersForOmegaT-1.8-1.40.0`.

Comment: @tomsgd commands are given options like this `command --long-something -short`. in this case the command also accepts a filename but that filename can start with a dash or two which will make the command try to interpret it as an options instead of a filename and would give unexpected results. a `--` tells the command that it shouldn't expect any more options and what comes are just space separated parameters which in this case is a filename

Comment: For `.tar.gz` files, or other "multiple extensions" with more than one dot. You may use: `extension="${filename#*.}"` and `filename="${filename%.$extension}"`. This will make filename the substring until the first dot.

Comment: For the meaning of `##` and `%`, see here: [percent symbol in Bash, what's it used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952009/4561887). This: `"${filename%.*}"`, for instance, means "delete the shortest match of `.` + 'whatever' from the end of `filename`". Read the `*` (asterisk/wildcard) as a glob-like "whatever", meaning that it can match any character, characters, or string.

Answer (score 1141):

```
~% FILE="example.tar.gz"

~% echo "${FILE%%.*}"
example

~% echo "${FILE%.*}"
example.tar

~% echo "${FILE#*.}"
tar.gz

~% echo "${FILE##*.}"
gz
```

For more details, see [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in the Bash manual.

Comment: You (perhaps unintentionally) bring up the excellent question of what to do if the "extension" part of the filename has 2 dots in it, as in .tar.gz... I've never considered that issue, and I suspect it's not solvable without knowing all the possible valid file extensions up front.

Comment: Why not solvable? In my example, it should be considered that the file contains *two* extensions, not an extension with two dots. You handle both extensions separately.

Comment: It is unsolvable on a lexical basis, you'll need to check the file type. Consider if you had a game called `dinosaurs.in.tar` and you gzipped it to `dinosaurs.in.tar.gz` :)

Comment: Doesn't work on Fedora 16 x86_64 GNU bash, version 4.2.20(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu). Both ${FILE#.*} and ${FILE##.*} return example.tar.gz.

Comment: This gets more complicated if you are passing in full paths.  One of mine had a '.' in a directory in the middle of the path, but none in the file name.  Example "a/b.c/d/e/filename" would wind up ".c/d/e/filename"

Comment: clearly no `x.tar.gz`'s extension is `gz` and the filename is `x.tar` that is it. There is no such thing as dual extensions. i'm pretty sure boost::filesystem handles it that way. (split path, change_extension...) and its behavior is based on python if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If your file has `.`s in it and and the "extension" `.tar.gz`, you can use `${FILE%.*.*}`

Comment: `echo "${FILE#*.}"` does not print an empty string when the filename has no extension.

Comment: For simple paths and in `zsh`, `echo "${${FILE##*/}%%.*}"` works. But yeah, then you can  also use `echo ${FILE:t:r:r}`.

Comment: Do note that this does not deal with hidden files, like `.gitignore`. The usual convention is that `.gitignore` is the name, and the file does not have an extension.

Answer (score 627):

Usually you already know the extension, so you might wish to use:

```
basename filename .extension
```

for example:

```
basename /path/to/dir/filename.txt .txt
```

and we get

```
filename
```

Comment: That second argument to `basename` is quite the eye-opener, ty kind sir/madam :)

Comment: And how to extract the extension, using this technique? ;) Oh, wait! We actually don't know it upfront.

Comment: Say you have a zipped directory that either ends with `.zip` or `.ZIP`. Is there a way you could do something like `basename $file {.zip,.ZIP}`?

Comment: While this only answers part of the OPs question, it does answer the question I typed into google.  :-)  Very slick!

Comment: easy and POSIX compliant

Comment: This works great! It also works with wildcards cause I didn't know the filename. Example: basename /path/to/dir/*.txt .txt ==> filename. This may not work if there are more than 1 .txt files in your directory. It works for me though.

Comment: Well played @tomi-po

Answer (score 215):

You can use the magic of POSIX parameter expansion:

```
bash-3.2$ FILENAME=somefile.tar.gz
bash-3.2$ echo "${FILENAME%%.*}"
somefile
bash-3.2$ echo "${FILENAME%.*}"
somefile.tar
```

---

There's a caveat in that if your filename was of the form `./somefile.tar.gz` then `echo ${FILENAME%%.*}` would greedily remove the longest match to the `.` and you'd have the empty string.

(You can work around that with a temporary variable:

```
FULL_FILENAME=$FILENAME
FILENAME=${FULL_FILENAME##*/}
echo ${FILENAME%%.*}
```

)

---

This [site](http://linuxgazette.net/18/bash.html) explains more.

```
${variable%pattern}
  Trim the shortest match from the end
${variable##pattern}
  Trim the longest match from the beginning
${variable%%pattern}
  Trim the longest match from the end
${variable#pattern}
  Trim the shortest match from the beginning
```

Comment: Much simpler than Joachim's answer but I always have to look up POSIX variable substitution. Also, this runs on Max OSX where `cut` doesn't have `--complement` and `sed` doesn't have `-r`.

Comment: works in git-bash for Windows - **GNU bash, version 5.2.15(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)** as well

Answer (score 93):

That doesn't seem to work if the file has no extension, or no filename.  Here is what I'm using; it only uses builtins and handles more (but not all) pathological filenames.

```
#!/bin/bash
for fullpath in "$@"
do
    filename="${fullpath##*/}"                      # Strip longest match of */ from start
    dir="${fullpath:0:${#fullpath} - ${#filename}}" # Substring from 0 thru pos of filename
    base="${filename%.[^.]*}"                       # Strip shortest match of . plus at least one non-dot char from end
    ext="${filename:${#base} + 1}"                  # Substring from len of base thru end
    if [[ -z "$base" && -n "$ext" ]]; then          # If we have an extension and no base, it's really the base
        base=".$ext"
        ext=""
    fi

    echo -e "$fullpath:\n\tdir  = \"$dir\"\n\tbase = \"$base\"\n\text  = \"$ext\""
done
```

And here are some testcases:

```
$ basename-and-extension.sh / /home/me/ /home/me/file /home/me/file.tar /home/me/file.tar.gz /home/me/.hidden /home/me/.hidden.tar /home/me/.. .
/:
    dir  = "/"
    base = ""
    ext  = ""
/home/me/:
    dir  = "/home/me/"
    base = ""
    ext  = ""
/home/me/file:
    dir  = "/home/me/"
    base = "file"
    ext  = ""
/home/me/file.tar:
    dir  = "/home/me/"
    base = "file"
    ext  = "tar"
/home/me/file.tar.gz:
    dir  = "/home/me/"
    base = "file.tar"
    ext  = "gz"
/home/me/.hidden:
    dir  = "/home/me/"
    base = ".hidden"
    ext  = ""
/home/me/.hidden.tar:
    dir  = "/home/me/"
    base = ".hidden"
    ext  = "tar"
/home/me/..:
    dir  = "/home/me/"
    base = ".."
    ext  = ""
.:
    dir  = ""
    base = "."
    ext  = ""
```

Comment: Instead of `dir="${fullpath:0:${#fullpath} - ${#filename}}"` I've often seen `dir="${fullpath%$filename}"`. It's simpler to write. Not sure if there is any real speed difference or gotchas.

Comment: This uses #!/bin/bash which is almost always wrong.  Prefer #!/bin/sh if possible or #!/usr/bin/env bash if not.

Comment: @Good Person: I don't know how it's almost always wrong: `which bash` -> `/bin/bash` ; perhaps it's your distro?

Comment: @vol7ron - on many distros bash is in /usr/local/bin/bash.  On OSX many people install a updated bash in /opt/local/bin/bash.  As such /bin/bash is wrong and one should use env to find it.  Even better is to use /bin/sh and POSIX constructs.  Except on solaris this is a POSIX shell.

Comment: @GoodPerson but if you are more comfortable with bash, why use sh?  Isn't that like saying, why use Perl when you can use sh?

Comment: @vol7ron if you use bash knowing it won't be portable - sure why not.  Its just like using python/ruby/etc.  It just happens to be that bash is not the default on a very large number of systems so it isn't a portable construct.  personally, I use zsh for scripts which only I use and POSIX sh for scripts which I share.

Comment: @vol7ron /bin/bash is not always the correct version of bash to run (in particular OSX users often install a newer version in /opt/local); in addition on the BSDs bash is rarely installed by default for technical and licensing reasons.  passing --posix doesn't help, just using the almost-certain-to-be-posix in the first place.  on the systems you checked does /bin/sh not exist?

Comment: @GoodPerson `/bin/bash` does exist, so why use `/bin/sh` if you prefer bash? Regarding different versions, then I would suggest `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (if it's really a concern); though, in recent times my setups are generally similar.  There are probably scripts that will conver your bash to POSIX if it becomes a problem, but if you have a preference, use the preference.

Comment: @vol7ron yes, this is what I said above: portable scripts are ideal.  If you must use a non-portable choice (zsh, bash, etc.) use env to find the binary.

Comment: @GoodPerson it seems you're right :) I think I was selectively-reading and concentrating on your `/bin/sh`, which I wasn't in total agreement with and thinking you were saying "don't use bash", but you were saying to use something more flexible if you do

Comment: This is a great solution, actually the only one that works in all the cases I want to cover

Comment: I haven't tested it extensively but I could get the extension with `ext="${filename##?(.)+([^.])?(.)}"` and the  name without extension then with `raw_name="${filename:0:${#filename} - ${#ext}}"` like this you at least won't need the conditional afterwards. It at least works for files without extension, multiple extensions like tar.gz and also files starting with a dot.

Comment: To remove the last `/` from `dir` use `dir_noslash="${dir%[/]}"`. (when creating folders etc)

Answer (score 80):

```
pax> echo a.b.js | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'
a.b
pax> echo a.b.js | sed 's/^.*\.//'
js
```

works fine, so you can just use:

```
pax> FILE=a.b.js
pax> NAME=$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//')
pax> EXTENSION=$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/^.*\.//')
pax> echo $NAME
a.b
pax> echo $EXTENSION
js
```

The commands, by the way, work as follows.

The command for `NAME` substitutes a `"."` character followed by any number of non-`"."` characters up to the end of the line, with nothing (i.e., it removes everything from the final `"."` to the end of the line, inclusive). This is basically a non-greedy substitution using regex trickery.

The command for `EXTENSION` substitutes a any number of characters followed by a `"."` character at the start of the line, with nothing (i.e., it removes everything from the start of the line to the final dot, inclusive). This is a greedy substitution which is the default action.

Comment: This break for files without extension as it would print the same for name and extension. So I use `sed 's,\.[^\.]*$,,'` for name, and `sed 's,.*\.,., ;t ;g'` for extension (uses the atypical `test` and `get` commands, along with the typical `substitute` command).

Comment: You could test, after calculating NAME, if it and FILE are equal, and if so set EXTENSION to the empty string.

Comment: Fundamentally, using an external process for something the shell can do itself is an antipattern.

Comment: tripleee: there are a great many things that the shell can do in a hundred lines that an external process like `awk` could do in five :-)

Comment: Does this handle multiple-part extensions, like `.tar.gz` ?

Comment: @jubilatious1: yes - that's a gzip file (that would usually hold a tar file within it) so the extension is `gz`. The definition I've used is that everything after the *final* `.` is the extension. If you need a different definition, you'll need to adjust for it but then you'll get into all sorts of edge cases like `user_pax.diablo_details.txt`. Is the extension there `txt` or `diablo_details.txt`? The latter would clearly be wrong in my opinion.

Answer (score 51):

You can use [`basename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename).

Example:

```
$ basename foo-bar.tar.gz .tar.gz
foo-bar
```

You do need to provide basename with the extension that shall be removed, however if you are always executing `tar` with `-z` then you know the extension will be `.tar.gz`.

This should do what you want:

```
tar -zxvf $1
cd $(basename $1 .tar.gz)
```

Comment: I suppose `cd $(basename $1 .tar.gz)` works for .gz files. But in question he mentioned `Archive files have several extensions: tar.gz, tat.xz, tar.bz2`

Comment: Tomi Po posted the same things 2 years before.

Comment: Hi Blauhirn, wauw this is an old questions. I think something have happened to the dates. I distinctively remember answering the question shortly after it was asked, and there where only a couple of other answers. Could it be that the question was merged with another one, does SO do that?

Comment: Yep I remember correctly. I originally answers this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703318/bash-script-remove-extension-from-file-name on the same day it was asked, 2 years later it was merged into this one. I can hardly be blamed for a duplicate answer when my answer was moved in this way.

Comment: This is a decade ago, haha.  I don't know why nobody mentioned it, but: `cd $(basename $1 .tar.*) ` is all it needs.

Answer (score 45):

Mellen writes in a comment on a blog post:

Using Bash, there’s also `${file%.*}` to get the filename without the extension and `${file##*.}` to get the extension alone. That is,

```
file="thisfile.txt"
echo "filename: ${file%.*}"
echo "extension: ${file##*.}"
```

Outputs:

```
filename: thisfile
extension: txt
```

Comment: @REACHUS: See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 37):

Here are some alternative suggestions (mostly in `awk`), including some advanced use cases, like extracting version numbers for software packages.

Just note that with a slightly different input some of these may fail, therefore anyone using these should validate on their expected input and adapt the regex expression if required.

```
f='/path/to/complex/file.1.0.1.tar.gz'

# Filename : 'file.1.0.x.tar.gz'
    echo "$f" | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'

# Extension (last): 'gz'
    echo "$f" | awk -F'[.]' '{print $NF}'
    
# Extension (all) : '1.0.1.tar.gz'
    echo "$f" | awk '{sub(/[^.]*[.]/, "", $0)} 1'
    
# Extension (last-2): 'tar.gz'
    echo "$f" | awk -F'[.]' '{print $(NF-1)"."$NF}'

# Basename : 'file'
    echo "$f" | awk '{gsub(/.*[/]|[.].*/, "", $0)} 1'

# Basename-extended : 'file.1.0.1.tar'
    echo "$f" | awk '{gsub(/.*[/]|[.]{1}[^.]+$/, "", $0)} 1'

# Path : '/path/to/complex/'
    echo "$f" | awk '{match($0, /.*[/]/, a); print a[0]}'
    # or 
    echo "$f" | grep -Eo '.*[/]'
    
# Folder (containing the file) : 'complex'
    echo "$f" | awk -F'/' '{$1=""; print $(NF-1)}'
    
# Version : '1.0.1'
    # Defined as 'number.number' or 'number.number.number'
    echo "$f" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+[.]+[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]?'

    # Version - major : '1'
    echo "$f" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+[.]+[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]?' | cut -d. -f1

    # Version - minor : '0'
    echo "$f" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+[.]+[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]?' | cut -d. -f2

    # Version - patch : '1'
    echo "$f" | grep -Eo '[0-9]+[.]+[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]?' | cut -d. -f3

# All Components : "path to complex file 1 0 1 tar gz"
    echo "$f" | awk -F'[/.]' '{$1=""; print $0}'
    
# Is absolute : True (exit-code : 0)
    # Return true if it is an absolute path (starting with '/' or '~/'
    echo "$f" | grep -q '^[/]\|^~/'
```

All use cases are using the original full path as input, without depending on intermediate results.

Comment: My version of awk doesn't like # Path : '/path/to/complex/'
    echo "$f" | awk '{match($0, /.*[/]/, a); print a[0]}'

Answer (score 35):

No need to bother with `awk` or `sed` or even `perl` for this simple task. There is a pure-Bash, `os.path.splitext()`-compatible solution which only uses parameter expansions.

## Reference Implementation

Documentation of [`os.path.splitext(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

> Split the pathname path into a pair `(root, ext)` such that `root + ext == path`, and *ext* is empty or begins with a period and contains at most one period. Leading periods on the basename are ignored; `splitext('.cshrc')` returns `('.cshrc', '')`.

Python code:

```
root, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
```

## Bash Implementation

### Honoring leading periods

```
root="${path%.*}"
ext="${path#"$root"}"
```

### Ignoring leading periods

```
root="${path#.}";root="${path%"$root"}${root%.*}"
ext="${path#"$root"}"
```

## Tests

Here are test cases for the *Ignoring leading periods* implementation, which should match the Python reference implementation on every input.

```
|---------------|-----------|-------|
|path           |root       |ext    |
|---------------|-----------|-------|
|' .txt'        |' '        |'.txt' |
|' .txt.txt'    |' .txt'    |'.txt' |
|' txt'         |' txt'     |''     |
|'*.txt.txt'    |'*.txt'    |'.txt' |
|'.cshrc'       |'.cshrc'   |''     |
|'.txt'         |'.txt'     |''     |
|'?.txt.txt'    |'?.txt'    |'.txt' |
|'\n.txt.txt'   |'\n.txt'   |'.txt' |
|'\t.txt.txt'   |'\t.txt'   |'.txt' |
|'a b.txt.txt'  |'a b.txt'  |'.txt' |
|'a*b.txt.txt'  |'a*b.txt'  |'.txt' |
|'a?b.txt.txt'  |'a?b.txt'  |'.txt' |
|'a\nb.txt.txt' |'a\nb.txt' |'.txt' |
|'a\tb.txt.txt' |'a\tb.txt' |'.txt' |
|'txt'          |'txt'      |''     |
|'txt.pdf'      |'txt'      |'.pdf' |
|'txt.tar.gz'   |'txt.tar'  |'.gz'  |
|'txt.txt'      |'txt'      |'.txt' |
|---------------|-----------|-------|
```

### Test Results

All tests passed.

Comment: no, the base file name for `text.tar.gz` should be `text` and extension be `.tar.gz`

Comment: @frederick99 As I said the solution here matches the implementation of `os.path.splitext` in Python. Whether that implementation is sane for possibly controversial inputs is another topic.

Comment: How do the quotes within the pattern (`"$root"`) work? What could happen if they were omitted? (I couldn't find any documentation on the matter.) Also how does this handle filenames with `*` or `?` in them?

Comment: Ok, testing shows me that the quotes make the pattern a literal, i.e.  `*` and `?` aren't special. So the two parts of my question answer each other. Am I correct that this isn't documented? Or is this supposed to be understood from the fact that quotes disable glob expansion in general?

Comment: Brilliant answer! I’ll just suggest a slightly simpler variant for computing the root: `root="${path#?}";root="${path::1}${root%.*}"` — then proceed the same to extract the extension.

Answer (score 29):

The **[accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/45375) works well in *typical* cases**, but **fails in *edge* cases**, namely:

- For filenames without extension (called *suffix* in the remainder of this answer), `extension=${filename##*.}` returns the input filename rather than an empty string.
- `extension=${filename##*.}` does not include the initial `.`, contrary to convention.

  - Blindly prepending `.` would not work for filenames without suffix.
- `filename="${filename%.*}"` will be the empty string, if the input file name starts with `.` and contains no further `.` characters (e.g., `.bash_profile`) - contrary to convention.

### ---------

Thus, the complexity of a **robust solution that covers all edge cases** calls for a **function** - see its definition below; it **can return *all* components of a path**.

Example call:

```
splitPath '/etc/bash.bashrc' dir fname fnameroot suffix
# -> $dir == '/etc'
# -> $fname == 'bash.bashrc'
# -> $fnameroot == 'bash'
# -> $suffix == '.bashrc'
```

Note that the arguments after the input path are freely chosen, positional variable *names*.
To skip variables not of interest that come before those that are, specify `_` (to use throw-away variable `$_`) or `''`; e.g., to extract filename root and extension only, use `splitPath '/etc/bash.bashrc' _ _ fnameroot extension`.

---

```
# SYNOPSIS
#   splitPath path varDirname [varBasename [varBasenameRoot [varSuffix]]] 
# DESCRIPTION
#   Splits the specified input path into its components and returns them by assigning
#   them to variables with the specified *names*.
#   Specify '' or throw-away variable _ to skip earlier variables, if necessary.
#   The filename suffix, if any, always starts with '.' - only the *last*
#   '.'-prefixed token is reported as the suffix.
#   As with `dirname`, varDirname will report '.' (current dir) for input paths
#   that are mere filenames, and '/' for the root dir.
#   As with `dirname` and `basename`, a trailing '/' in the input path is ignored.
#   A '.' as the very first char. of a filename is NOT considered the beginning
#   of a filename suffix.
# EXAMPLE
#   splitPath '/home/jdoe/readme.txt' parentpath fname fnameroot suffix
#   echo "$parentpath" # -> '/home/jdoe'
#   echo "$fname" # -> 'readme.txt'
#   echo "$fnameroot" # -> 'readme'
#   echo "$suffix" # -> '.txt'
#   ---
#   splitPath '/home/jdoe/readme.txt' _ _ fnameroot
#   echo "$fnameroot" # -> 'readme'  
splitPath() {
  local _sp_dirname= _sp_basename= _sp_basename_root= _sp_suffix=
    # simple argument validation
  (( $# >= 2 )) || { echo "$FUNCNAME: ERROR: Specify an input path and at least 1 output variable name." >&2; exit 2; }
    # extract dirname (parent path) and basename (filename)
  _sp_dirname=$(dirname "$1")
  _sp_basename=$(basename "$1")
    # determine suffix, if any
  _sp_suffix=$([[ $_sp_basename = *.* ]] && printf %s ".${_sp_basename##*.}" || printf '')
    # determine basename root (filemane w/o suffix)
  if [[ "$_sp_basename" == "$_sp_suffix" ]]; then # does filename start with '.'?
      _sp_basename_root=$_sp_basename
      _sp_suffix=''
  else # strip suffix from filename
    _sp_basename_root=${_sp_basename%$_sp_suffix}
  fi
  # assign to output vars.
  [[ -n $2 ]] && printf -v "$2" "$_sp_dirname"
  [[ -n $3 ]] && printf -v "$3" "$_sp_basename"
  [[ -n $4 ]] && printf -v "$4" "$_sp_basename_root"
  [[ -n $5 ]] && printf -v "$5" "$_sp_suffix"
  return 0
}

test_paths=(
  '/etc/bash.bashrc'
  '/usr/bin/grep'
  '/Users/jdoe/.bash_profile'
  '/Library/Application Support/'
  'readme.new.txt'
)

for p in "${test_paths[@]}"; do
  echo ----- "$p"
  parentpath= fname= fnameroot= suffix=
  splitPath "$p" parentpath fname fnameroot suffix
  for n in parentpath fname fnameroot suffix; do
    echo "$n=${!n}"
  done
done
```

Test code that exercises the function:

```
test_paths=(
  '/etc/bash.bashrc'
  '/usr/bin/grep'
  '/Users/jdoe/.bash_profile'
  '/Library/Application Support/'
  'readme.new.txt'
)

for p in "${test_paths[@]}"; do
  echo ----- "$p"
  parentpath= fname= fnameroot= suffix=
  splitPath "$p" parentpath fname fnameroot suffix
  for n in parentpath fname fnameroot suffix; do
    echo "$n=${!n}"
  done
done
```

Expected output - note the edge cases:

- a filename having no suffix
- a filename starting with `.` (*not* considered the start of the suffix)
- an input path ending in `/` (trailing `/` is ignored)
- an input path that is a filename only (`.` is returned as the parent path)
- a filename that has more than `.`-prefixed token (only the last is considered the suffix):

```
----- /etc/bash.bashrc
parentpath=/etc
fname=bash.bashrc
fnameroot=bash
suffix=.bashrc
----- /usr/bin/grep
parentpath=/usr/bin
fname=grep
fnameroot=grep
suffix=
----- /Users/jdoe/.bash_profile
parentpath=/Users/jdoe
fname=.bash_profile
fnameroot=.bash_profile
suffix=
----- /Library/Application Support/
parentpath=/Library
fname=Application Support
fnameroot=Application Support
suffix=
----- readme.new.txt
parentpath=.
fname=readme.new.txt
fnameroot=readme.new
suffix=.txt
```

Answer (score 27):

You could use the [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) command to remove the last two extensions (the `".tar.gz"` part):

```
$ echo "foo.tar.gz" | cut -d'.' --complement -f2-
foo
```

---

As noted by Clayton Hughes in a comment, this will not work for the actual example in the question. So as an alternative I propose using `sed` with extended regular expressions, like this:

```
$ echo "mpc-1.0.1.tar.gz" | sed -r 's/\.[[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]+$//'
mpc-1.0.1
```

It works by removing the last two (alpha-numeric) extensions unconditionally.

[Updated again after comment from Anders Lindahl]

Comment: This only works in the case where the filename/path doesn't contain any other dots:  echo "mpc-1.0.1.tar.gz" | cut -d'.' --complement -f2- produces "mpc-1" (just the first 2 fields after delimiting by .)

Comment: @ClaytonHughes You're correct, and I should have tested it better. Added another solution.

Comment: The sed expressions should use `$` to check that the matched extension is at the end of the file name. Otherwise, a filename like `i.like.tar.gz.files.tar.bz2` might produce unexpected result.

Comment: @AndersLindahl It still will, if the order of the extensions is the reverse of the `sed` chain order. Even with `$` at the end a filename such as `mpc-1.0.1.tar.bz2.tar.gz` will remove both `.tar.gz` and then `.tar.bz2`.

Comment: $ echo "foo.tar.gz" | cut -d'.'  -f2-  

WITHOUT --complement  

will get the 2nd split item to the end of the string  


    $ echo "foo.tar.gz" | cut -d'.' -f2-  
    tar.gz

Answer (score 24):

Smallest and simplest solution (in single line) is:

```
$ file=/blaabla/bla/blah/foo.txt
echo $(basename ${file%.*}) # foo
```

Comment: That's a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo). In general, `echo $(command)` is better written simply `command` unless you specifically require the shell to perform whitespace tokenization and wildcard expansion on the output from `command` before displaying the result.  Quiz: what's the output of `echo $(echo '*')` (and if that's what you really want, you really really want just `echo *`).

Comment: @triplee I didn't use `echo` command at all. I just used it to demonstrate the result `foo` which is appearing in the 3rd line as the result of the 2nd line.

Comment: But just `basename "${file%.*}"` would do the same; you are using a command substitution to capture its output, only to `echo` that same output immediately. (Without quoting, the result is nominally different; but that's hardly relevant, much less a feature, here.)

Comment: Also `basename "$file" .txt` avoids the complexity of the parameter substitution.

Comment: Just read my previous reply carefully before talking about unrelated stuff and wasting our time. Thanks

Comment: @Ron Read his first comment before accusing him of wasting our time.

Comment: @frederick99 I did. And I replied!. He's talking blah blah about `echo` which is not even a the part of the command. all you need to extract from my code is this part: `$(basename ${file%.*})` Don't even look at `echo`. It has no purpose, but It's still in the example just to help people to get a clear idea about what's happening under the hood. `echo` is completely unrelated to this topic "extract filename and extension in bash".

Comment: @Ron I know it's not related to the question but he had a point, even if it was not relevant. I felt what he said was interesting and definitely not a waste of time (unlike this :l).

Comment: Try it with a file name with one or more consecutive spaces in it. :)

Answer (score 18):

I think that if you just need the name of the file, you can try this:

```
FULLPATH=/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf

# Remove all the prefix until the "/" character
FILENAME=${FULLPATH##*/}

# Remove all the prefix until the "." character
FILEEXTENSION=${FILENAME##*.}

# Remove a suffix, in our case, the filename. This will return the name of the directory that contains this file.
BASEDIRECTORY=${FULLPATH%$FILENAME}

echo "path = $FULLPATH"
echo "file name = $FILENAME"
echo "file extension = $FILEEXTENSION"
echo "base directory = $BASEDIRECTORY"
```

And that is all =D.

Answer (score 14):

```
$ F="text file.test.txt"  
$ echo ${F/*./}  
txt
```

This caters for multiple dots and spaces in a filename, however if there is no extension it returns the filename itself. Easy to check for though; just test for the filename and extension being the same.

Naturally this method doesn't work for .tar.gz files. However that could be handled in a two step process. If the extension is gz then check again to see if there is also a tar extension.

Comment: very clean and straightforward answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

You can force cut to display all fields and subsequent ones adding `-` to field number.

```
NAME=`basename "$FILE"`
EXTENSION=`echo "$NAME" | cut -d'.' -f2-`
```

So if FILE is `eth0.pcap.gz`, the EXTENSION will be `pcap.gz`

Using the same logic, you can also fetch the file name using '-' with cut as follows :

```
NAME=`basename "$FILE" | cut -d'.' -f-1`
```

This works even for filenames that do not have any extension.

Answer (score 12):

This is the only one that worked for me:

```sh
path='folder/other_folder/file.js'

base=${path##*/}
echo ${base%.*}

>> file
```

This can also be used in string interpolation as well, but unfortunately you have to set `base` beforehand.

Answer (score 11):

#### Magic file recognition

In addition to the lot of good answers on this Stack Overflow question I would like to add:

Under Linux and other unixen, there is a *magic* command named `file`, that do filetype detection by analysing some first bytes of file. This is a very old tool, initialy used for print servers (if not created for... I'm not sure about that).

```
file myfile.txt
myfile.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text

file -b --mime-type myfile.txt
text/plain
```

Standards extensions could be found in `/etc/mime.types` (on my [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) GNU/Linux desktop. See `man file` and `man mime.types`. Perhaps you have to install the `file` utility and `mime-support` packages):

```
grep $( file -b --mime-type myfile.txt ) </etc/mime.types
text/plain      asc txt text pot brf srt
```

You could create a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) function for determining right extension.
There is a little (not perfect) sample:

```
file2ext() {
    local _mimetype=$(file -Lb --mime-type "$1") _line _basemimetype
    case ${_mimetype##*[/.-]} in
        gzip | bzip2 | xz | z )
            _mimetype=${_mimetype##*[/.-]}
            _mimetype=${_mimetype//ip}
            _basemimetype=$(file -zLb --mime-type "$1")
            ;;
        stream )
            _mimetype=($(file -Lb "$1"))
            [ "${_mimetype[1]}" = "compressed" ] &&
                _basemimetype=$(file -b --mime-type - < <(
                        ${_mimetype,,} -d <"$1")) ||
                _basemimetype=${_mimetype,,}
            _mimetype=${_mimetype,,}
            ;;
        executable )  _mimetype='' _basemimetype='' ;;
        dosexec )     _mimetype='' _basemimetype='exe' ;;
        shellscript ) _mimetype='' _basemimetype='sh' ;;
        * )
            _basemimetype=$_mimetype
            _mimetype=''
            ;;
    esac
    while read -a _line ;do
        if [ "$_line" == "$_basemimetype" ] ;then
            [ "$_line[1]" ] &&
                _basemimetype=${_line[1]} ||
                _basemimetype=${_basemimetype##*[/.-]}
            break
        fi
        done </etc/mime.types
    case ${_basemimetype##*[/.-]} in
        executable ) _basemimetype='' ;;
        shellscript ) _basemimetype='sh' ;;
        dosexec ) _basemimetype='exe' ;;
        * ) ;;
    esac
    [ "$_mimetype" ] && [ "$_basemimetype" != "$_mimetype" ] &&
      printf ${2+-v} $2 "%s.%s" ${_basemimetype##*[/.-]} ${_mimetype##*[/.-]} ||
      printf ${2+-v} $2 "%s" ${_basemimetype##*[/.-]}
}
```

This function could set a Bash variable that can be used later:

(This is inspired from @Petesh right answer):

```
filename=$(basename "$fullfile")
filename="${filename%.*}"
file2ext "$fullfile" extension

echo "$fullfile -> $filename . $extension"
```

Comment: Although not a direct answer to the original post, this is by far the most sensible response.  Thanks for providing it.

Comment: I really appreciate this thorough answer highlighting common built-ins. Though I ended up just doing this in python using the `-c` flag, if I were constrained to using just shell scripting I'd use the concepts outlined herein. Thank you!

Comment: @JasonRStevensCFA under python, you will use  [python-magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70711868/1765658) library!

Comment: @F.Hauri Cool lib, thanks for sharing. I just use standard stuff as the string builtins for scripting are _beyond simple_. For example, `$(python -c "'$1'.split('/')[-1]")` will get you the filename with extension from a path string variable `$1` using a subshell (I use it like this in some local scripts). I don't use this kind of "magic" in prod but these features of the Python language are fantastic for simple task-based things.

Comment: @JasonRStevensCFA Using forks to python, like any other language (perl, awk, etc...) for so tiny requirment is counter-productive! Try to run same fork 1000 time and compare with *parameter expansion*...

Comment: @F.Hauri "I don't use this kind of "magic" in prod but these features of the Python language are fantastic for simple task-based things" 

That's why I qualified what I wrote ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Ok so if I understand correctly, the problem here is how to get the name and the full extension of a file that has multiple extensions, e.g., `stuff.tar.gz`.

This works for me:

```
fullfile="stuff.tar.gz"
fileExt=${fullfile#*.}
fileName=${fullfile%*.$fileExt}
```

This will give you `stuff` as filename and `.tar.gz` as extension. It works for any number of extensions, including 0. Hope this helps for anyone having the same problem =)

Comment: The correct result (according to `os.path.splitext`, which is what the OP wants) is `('stuff.tar', '.gz')`.

Answer (score 9):

Simply use `${parameter%word}`

In your case:

```
${FILE%.*}
```

If you want to test it, all following work, and just remove the extension:

```
FILE=abc.xyz; echo ${FILE%.*};
FILE=123.abc.xyz; echo ${FILE%.*};
FILE=abc; echo ${FILE%.*};
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It's still useful, although there shouldn't be spaces around the `=` signs.

Comment: This works fine. Thank you! (now it doesn't have the spaces around the equal signs, if that was why it was downvoted)

Comment: Won't work for dotfiles and needs quotes.

Answer (score 8):

<sup>**No previous answer used a bash regex**</sup>
Here's a pure bash solution that splits a **path** into:

- The *directory path*, with its trailing `/` when present
  <sup>The regex that discards the trailing `/` is so much longer that I didn't post it</sup>
- The *filename*, excluding the (last) *dot extension*
- The (last) *dot extension*, with its leading `.`

<sub>The code is meant to handle every possible case, you're welcome to try it.</sub>

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for path; do

####### the relevant part ######

[[ $path =~ ^(\.{1,2}|.*/\.{0,2})$|^(.*/)([^/]+)(\.[^/]*)$|^(.*/)(.+)$|^(.+)(\..*)$|^(.+)$ ]]

dirpath=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
filename=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[6]}${BASH_REMATCH[7]}${BASH_REMATCH[9]}
filext=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}${BASH_REMATCH[8]}

# dirpath should be non-null
[[ $dirpath ]] || dirpath='.'

################################

printf '%s=%q\n' \
    path     "$path" \
    dirpath  "$dirpath" \
    filename "$filename" \
    filext   "$filext"

done
```

How does it work?

Basically, it ensures that only one sub-expression (delimited with `|` in the regex) is able to capture the input. Thanks to that, you can concatenate all the capture groups of the same type (for example, the ones related to the directory path) stored in `BASH_REMATCH`, because at most one will be non-null.

###### Here are the results of an extended but not exhaustive set of examples:

```bash
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| input             dirpath        filename       filext |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
''                  .              ''             ''
.                   .              ''             ''
..                  ..             ''             ''
...                 .              ..             .
.file               .              .file          ''
.file.              .              .file          .
.file..             .              .file.         .
.file.Z             .              .file          .Z
.file.sh.Z          .              .file.sh       .Z
file                .              file           ''
file.               .              file           .
file..              .              file.          .
file.Z              .              file           .Z
file.sh.Z           .              file.sh        .Z
dir/                dir/           ''             ''
dir/.               dir/.          ''             ''
dir/...             dir/           ..             .
dir/.file           dir/           .file          ''
dir/.file.          dir/           .file          .
dir/.file..         dir/           .file.         .
dir/.file.Z         dir/           .file          .Z
dir/.file.x.Z       dir/           .file.x        .Z
dir/file            dir/           file           ''
dir/file.           dir/           file           .
dir/file..          dir/           file.          .
dir/file.Z          dir/           file           .Z
dir/file.x.Z        dir/           file.x         .Z
dir./.              dir./.         ''             ''
dir./...            dir./          ..             .
dir./.file          dir./          .file          ''
dir./.file.         dir./          .file          .
dir./.file..        dir./          .file.         .
dir./.file.Z        dir./          .file          .Z
dir./.file.sh.Z     dir./          .file.sh       .Z
dir./file           dir./          file           ''
dir./file.          dir./          file           .
dir./file..         dir./          file.          .
dir./file.Z         dir./          file           .Z
dir./file.x.Z       dir./          file.x         .Z
dir//               dir//          ''             ''
dir//.              dir//.         ''             ''
dir//...            dir//          ..             .
dir//.file          dir//          .file          ''
dir//.file.         dir//          .file          .
dir//.file..        dir//          .file.         .
dir//.file.Z        dir//          .file          .Z
dir//.file.x.Z      dir//          .file.x        .Z
dir//file           dir//          file           ''
dir//file.          dir//          file           .
dir//file..         dir//          file.          .
dir//file.Z         dir//          file           .Z
dir//file.x.Z       dir//          file.x         .Z
dir.//.             dir.//.        ''             ''
dir.//...           dir.//         ..             .
dir.//.file         dir.//         .file          ''
dir.//.file.        dir.//         .file          .
dir.//.file..       dir.//         .file.         .
dir.//.file.Z       dir.//         .file          .Z
dir.//.file.x.Z     dir.//         .file.x        .Z
dir.//file          dir.//         file           ''
dir.//file.         dir.//         file           .
dir.//file..        dir.//         file.          .
dir.//file.Z        dir.//         file           .Z
dir.//file.x.Z      dir.//         file.x         .Z
/                   /              ''             ''
/.                  /.             ''             ''
/..                 /..            ''             ''
/...                /              ..             .
/.file              /              .file          ''
/.file.             /              .file          .
/.file..            /              .file.         .
/.file.Z            /              .file          .Z
/.file.sh.Z         /              .file.sh       .Z
/file               /              file           ''
/file.              /              file           .
/file..             /              file.          .
/file.Z             /              file           .Z
/file.sh.Z          /              file.sh        .Z
/dir/               /dir/          ''             ''
/dir/.              /dir/.         ''             ''
/dir/...            /dir/          ..             .
/dir/.file          /dir/          .file          ''
/dir/.file.         /dir/          .file          .
/dir/.file..        /dir/          .file.         .
/dir/.file.Z        /dir/          .file          .Z
/dir/.file.x.Z      /dir/          .file.x        .Z
/dir/file           /dir/          file           ''
/dir/file.          /dir/          file           .
/dir/file..         /dir/          file.          .
/dir/file.Z         /dir/          file           .Z
/dir/file.x.Z       /dir/          file.x         .Z
/dir./.             /dir./.        ''             ''
/dir./...           /dir./         ..             .
/dir./.file         /dir./         .file          ''
/dir./.file.        /dir./         .file          .
/dir./.file..       /dir./         .file.         .
/dir./.file.Z       /dir./         .file          .Z
/dir./.file.sh.Z    /dir./         .file.sh       .Z
/dir./file          /dir./         file           ''
/dir./file.         /dir./         file           .
/dir./file..        /dir./         file.          .
/dir./file.Z        /dir./         file           .Z
/dir./file.x.Z      /dir./         file.x         .Z
/dir//              /dir//         ''             ''
/dir//.             /dir//.        ''             ''
/dir//...           /dir//         ..             .
/dir//.file         /dir//         .file          ''
/dir//.file.        /dir//         .file          .
/dir//.file..       /dir//         .file.         .
/dir//.file.Z       /dir//         .file          .Z
/dir//.file.x.Z     /dir//         .file.x        .Z
/dir//file          /dir//         file           ''
/dir//file.         /dir//         file           .
/dir//file..        /dir//         file.          .
/dir//file.Z        /dir//         file           .Z
/dir//file.x.Z      /dir//         file.x         .Z
/dir.//.            /dir.//.       ''             ''
/dir.//...          /dir.//        ..             .
/dir.//.file        /dir.//        .file          ''
/dir.//.file.       /dir.//        .file          .
/dir.//.file..      /dir.//        .file.         .
/dir.//.file.Z      /dir.//        .file          .Z
/dir.//.file.x.Z    /dir.//        .file.x        .Z
/dir.//file         /dir.//        file           ''
/dir.//file.        /dir.//        file           .
/dir.//file..       /dir.//        file.          .
/dir.//file.Z       /dir.//        file           .Z
/dir.//file.x.Z     /dir.//        file.x         .Z
//                  //             ''             ''
//.                 //.            ''             ''
//..                //..           ''             ''
//...               //             ..             .
//.file             //             .file          ''
//.file.            //             .file          .
//.file..           //             .file.         .
//.file.Z           //             .file          .Z
//.file.sh.Z        //             .file.sh       .Z
//file              //             file           ''
//file.             //             file           .
//file..            //             file.          .
//file.Z            //             file           .Z
//file.sh.Z         //             file.sh        .Z
//dir/              //dir/         ''             ''
//dir/.             //dir/.        ''             ''
//dir/...           //dir/         ..             .
//dir/.file         //dir/         .file          ''
//dir/.file.        //dir/         .file          .
//dir/.file..       //dir/         .file.         .
//dir/.file.Z       //dir/         .file          .Z
//dir/.file.x.Z     //dir/         .file.x        .Z
//dir/file          //dir/         file           ''
//dir/file.         //dir/         file           .
//dir/file..        //dir/         file.          .
//dir/file.Z        //dir/         file           .Z
//dir/file.x.Z      //dir/         file.x         .Z
//dir./.            //dir./.       ''             ''
//dir./...          //dir./        ..             .
//dir./.file        //dir./        .file          ''
//dir./.file.       //dir./        .file          .
//dir./.file..      //dir./        .file.         .
//dir./.file.Z      //dir./        .file          .Z
//dir./.file.sh.Z   //dir./        .file.sh       .Z
//dir./file         //dir./        file           ''
//dir./file.        //dir./        file           .
//dir./file..       //dir./        file.          .
//dir./file.Z       //dir./        file           .Z
//dir./file.x.Z     //dir./        file.x         .Z
//dir//             //dir//        ''             ''
//dir//.            //dir//.       ''             ''
//dir//...          //dir//        ..             .
//dir//.file        //dir//        .file          ''
//dir//.file.       //dir//        .file          .
//dir//.file..      //dir//        .file.         .
//dir//.file.Z      //dir//        .file          .Z
//dir//.file.x.Z    //dir//        .file.x        .Z
//dir//file         //dir//        file           ''
//dir//file.        //dir//        file           .
//dir//file..       //dir//        file.          .
//dir//file.Z       //dir//        file           .Z
//dir//file.x.Z     //dir//        file.x         .Z
//dir.//.           //dir.//.      ''             ''
//dir.//...         //dir.//       ..             .
//dir.//.file       //dir.//       .file          ''
//dir.//.file.      //dir.//       .file          .
//dir.//.file..     //dir.//       .file.         .
//dir.//.file.Z     //dir.//       .file          .Z
//dir.//.file.x.Z   //dir.//       .file.x        .Z
//dir.//file        //dir.//       file           ''
//dir.//file.       //dir.//       file           .
//dir.//file..      //dir.//       file.          .
//dir.//file.Z      //dir.//       file           .Z
//dir.//file.x.Z    //dir.//       file.x         .Z
```

As you can see, the behaviour is different from `basename` and `dirname`.
For example `basename dir/` outputs `dir` while the regex will give you an empty filename for it. Same for `.` and `..`, those are considered directories, not filenames.

I timed it with 10000 paths of 256 characters and it took about 1 second, while the equivalent POSIX shell solution is 2x slower and solutions based on wild forking (external calls inside the `for` loop) are at least 60x slower.

**remark:** It's not necessary to test paths that contain `\n` or other notorious characters because all characters are handled the same way by the regex engine of bash. The only characters that would be able to break the current logic are `/` and `.`, intermixed or multiplied in a *currently* unexpected way. When I first posted my answer I found a few border cases that I had to fix; I can't say that the regex is 100% bullet proof but it should be quite robust now.

---

As an aside, here's the POSIX shell solution that yields the same output:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

for path; do

####### the relevant part ######

fullname=${path##*/}

case $fullname in
. | ..)
    dirpath="$path"
    filename=''
    filext=''
    ;;
*)
    dirpath=${path%"$fullname"}
    dirpath=${dirpath:-.}       # dirpath should be non-null
    filename=${fullname#.}
    filename="${fullname%"$filename"}${filename%.*}"
    filext=${fullname#"$filename"}
    ;;
esac

################################

printf '%s=%s\n' \
    path     "$path" \
    dirpath  "$dirpath" \
    filename "$filename" \
    filext   "$filext"

done
```

---

**postscript:** There are a few points for which some people might disagree with the results given by the above codes:

- The special case of **dotfiles**: The reason is that dotfiles **are** a UNIX concept.
- The special case of `.` and `..`: IMHO it seems obvious to treat them as directories, but most libraries don't do that and force the user to post-process the result.
- No support for double-extensions: That's because you'd need a whole database for storing all the valid double-extensions, and above all, because file extensions don't mean anything in UNIX; for example you can call a tar archive `my_tarred_files` and that's completely fine, you'll be able to `tar xf my_tarred_files` without any problem.

Answer (score 7):

I use the following script

```
$ echo "foo.tar.gz"|rev|cut -d"." -f3-|rev
foo
```

Comment: This is not efficient at all.  To forks too many times which is quite unnecessary since this operation can be performed in pure Bash without the need for any external commands and forking.

Answer (score 7):

How to extract the filename and extension in [**fish**](http://fishshell.com/):

```
function split-filename-extension --description "Prints the filename and extension"
  for file in $argv
    if test -f $file
      set --local extension (echo $file | awk -F. '{print $NF}')
      set --local filename (basename $file .$extension)
      echo "$filename $extension"
    else
      echo "$file is not a valid file"
    end
  end
end
```

**Caveats:** Splits on the last dot, which works well for filenames with dots in them, but not well for extensions with dots in them. See example below.

**Usage:**

```
$ split-filename-extension foo-0.4.2.zip bar.tar.gz
foo-0.4.2 zip  # Looks good!
bar.tar gz  # Careful, you probably want .tar.gz as the extension.
```

There's probably better ways to do this. Feel free to edit my answer to improve it.

---

If there's a limited set of extensions you'll be dealing with and you know all of them, try this:

```
switch $file
  case *.tar
    echo (basename $file .tar) tar
  case *.tar.bz2
    echo (basename $file .tar.bz2) tar.bz2
  case *.tar.gz
    echo (basename $file .tar.gz) tar.gz
  # and so on
end
```

This does **not** have the caveat as the first example, but you do have to handle every case so it could be more tedious depending on how many extensions you can expect.

Answer (score 7):

Building from [Petesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/921580) answer, if only the filename is needed,
both path and extension can be stripped in a single line,

```
filename=$(basename ${fullname%.*})
```

Comment: Did not work for me: "basename: missing operand
Try 'basename --help' for more information."

Comment: Strange, are you certain you're using Bash? In my case, with both versions 3.2.25 (old CentOS) and 4.3.30 (Debian Jessie) it works flawlessly.

Comment: Maybe there is a space in the filename?  Try using `filename="$(basename "${fullname%.*}")"`

Comment: The second argument to `basename` is optional, but specifies the extension to strip off. The substitution might still be useful but perhaps `basename` actually isn't, since you can actually perform all of these substitutions with shell builtins.

Answer (score 6):

Here is code with [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK). It can be done more simply. But I am not good in AWK.

```
filename$ ls
abc.a.txt  a.b.c.txt  pp-kk.txt
filename$ find . -type f | awk -F/ '{print $2}' | rev | awk -F"." '{$1="";print}' | rev | awk 'gsub(" ",".") ,sub(".$", "")'
abc.a
a.b.c
pp-kk
filename$ find . -type f | awk -F/ '{print $2}' | awk -F"." '{print $NF}'
txt
txt
txt
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the first awk statement in the last example, right?

Comment: You can avoid piping Awk to Awk by doing another `split()`.  `awk -F / '{ n=split($2, a, "."); print a[n] }' uses `/` as the top-level delimiter but then splits the second fields on `.` and prints the last element from the new array.

Answer (score 5):

Based largely off of @mklement0's excellent, and chock-full of random, useful *bashisms* - as well as other answers to this / other questions / "that darn internet"... I wrapped it all up in a little, slightly more comprehensible, reusable *function* for my (or your) `.bash_profile` that takes care of what (I consider) should be a more robust version of `dirname`/`basename` / *what have you*..

```
function path { SAVEIFS=$IFS; IFS=""   # stash IFS for safe-keeping, etc.
    [[ $# != 2 ]] && echo "usage: path <path> <dir|name|fullname|ext>" && return    # demand 2 arguments
    [[ $1 =~ ^(.*/)?(.+)?$ ]] && {     # regex parse the path
        dir=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        file=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        ext=$([[ $file = *.* ]] && printf %s ${file##*.} || printf '')
        # edge cases for extensionless files and files like ".nesh_profile.coffee"
        [[ $file == $ext ]] && fnr=$file && ext='' || fnr=${file:0:$((${#file}-${#ext}))}
        case "$2" in
             dir) echo      "${dir%/*}"; ;;
            name) echo      "${fnr%.*}"; ;;
        fullname) echo "${fnr%.*}.$ext"; ;;
             ext) echo           "$ext"; ;;
        esac
    }
    IFS=$SAVEIFS
}
```

Usage examples...

```
SOMEPATH=/path/to.some/.random\ file.gzip
path $SOMEPATH dir        # /path/to.some
path $SOMEPATH name       # .random file
path $SOMEPATH ext        # gzip
path $SOMEPATH fullname   # .random file.gzip                     
path gobbledygook         # usage: -bash <path> <dir|name|fullname|ext>
```

Comment: Nicely done; a few suggestions: - You don't seem to be relying on `$IFS` at all (and if you were, you could use `local` to localize the effect of setting it). - Better to use `local` variables. - Your error message should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` (use `1>&2`), and you should return a non-zero exit code. - Better to rename `fullname` to `basename` (the former suggests a path with dir components). - `name` unconditionally appends a `.` (period), even if the original had none. You could simply use the `basename` utility, but note that it ignores a terminating `/`.

Answer (score 4):

A simple answer:

To expand on the [**POSIX variables** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703318/bash-script-remove-extension-from-file-name#14703709), note that you can do more interesting patterns. So for the case detailed here, you could simply do this:

```
tar -zxvf $1
cd ${1%.tar.*}
```

That will cut off the last occurrence of .tar.*<something>*.

More generally, if you wanted to remove the last occurrence of .*<something>*.*<something-else>* then

```
${1.*.*}
```

should work fine.

The link the above answer appears to be dead. [Here's a great explanation of a bunch of the string manipulation you can do directly in Bash, from TLDP](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: Is there a way to make the match case-insensitive?

Answer (score 3):

If you also want to allow **empty** extensions, this is the shortest I could come up with:

```
echo 'hello.txt' | sed -r 's/.+\.(.+)|.*/\1/' # EXTENSION
echo 'hello.txt' | sed -r 's/(.+)\..+|(.*)/\1\2/' # FILENAME
```

1st line explained: It matches PATH.EXT or ANYTHING and replaces it with EXT. If ANYTHING was matched, the ext group is not captured.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO the best solution has already been given (using shell parameter expansion) and are the best rated one at this time.

I however add this one which just use dumbs commands, which is not efficient and which noone serious should use ever :

```
FILENAME=$(echo $FILE | cut -d . -f 1-$(printf $FILE | tr . '\n' | wc -l))
EXTENSION=$(echo $FILE | tr . '\n' | tail -1)
```

Added **just for fun** :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the algorithm I used for finding the name and extension of a file when I wrote a Bash script to make names unique when names conflicted with respect to casing.

```
#! /bin/bash 

#
# Finds 
# -- name and extension pairs
# -- null extension when there isn't an extension.
# -- Finds name of a hidden file without an extension
# 

declare -a fileNames=(
  '.Montreal' 
  '.Rome.txt' 
  'Loundon.txt' 
  'Paris' 
  'San Diego.txt'
  'San Francisco' 
  )

echo "Script ${0} finding name and extension pairs."
echo 

for theFileName in "${fileNames[@]}"
do
     echo "theFileName=${theFileName}"  

     # Get the proposed name by chopping off the extension
     name="${theFileName%.*}"

     # get extension.  Set to null when there isn't an extension
     # Thanks to mklement0 in a comment above.
     extension=$([[ "$theFileName" == *.* ]] && echo ".${theFileName##*.}" || echo '')

     # a hidden file without extenson?
     if [ "${theFileName}" = "${extension}" ] ; then
         # hidden file without extension.  Fixup.
         name=${theFileName}
         extension=""
     fi

     echo "  name=${name}"
     echo "  extension=${extension}"
done
```

The test run.

```
$ config/Name\&Extension.bash 
Script config/Name&Extension.bash finding name and extension pairs.

theFileName=.Montreal
  name=.Montreal
  extension=
theFileName=.Rome.txt
  name=.Rome
  extension=.txt
theFileName=Loundon.txt
  name=Loundon
  extension=.txt
theFileName=Paris
  name=Paris
  extension=
theFileName=San Diego.txt
  name=San Diego
  extension=.txt
theFileName=San Francisco
  name=San Francisco
  extension=
$
```

FYI: The complete transliteration program and more test cases can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4c6m0f2e28a1vxf/avoid-clashes-code.zip?dl=0

Comment: From all the solutions this is the only one that returns an empty string when the file has no extension with: `extension=$([[ "$theFileName" == *.* ]] && echo ".${theFileName##*.}" || echo '')`

Answer (score 1):

Using example file `/Users/Jonathan/Scripts/bash/MyScript.sh`, this code:

```
MY_EXT=".${0##*.}"
ME=$(/usr/bin/basename "${0}" "${MY_EXT}")
```

will result in `${ME}` being `MyScript` and `${MY_EXT}` being `.sh`:

---

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

MY_EXT=".${0##*.}"
ME=$(/usr/bin/basename "${0}" "${MY_EXT}")

echo "${ME} - ${MY_EXT}"
```

Some tests:

```
$ ./MyScript.sh 
MyScript - .sh

$ bash MyScript.sh
MyScript - .sh

$ /Users/Jonathan/Scripts/bash/MyScript.sh
MyScript - .sh

$ bash /Users/Jonathan/Scripts/bash/MyScript.sh
MyScript - .sh
```

Comment: Not sure why this has so many downvotes - it's actually more efficient than the accepted answer. (As the latter, it also breaks with input filenames _without_ an extension). Using an explicit path to `basename` is, perhaps, overkill.

Answer (score 1):

From the answers above, the shortest oneliner to mimic Python's

```
file, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
```

presuming your file really does have an extension, is

```
EXT="${PATH##*.}"; FILE=$(basename "$PATH" .$EXT)
```

Comment: I've got downvotes on this. I'm considering to remove the answer, people somehow dislike it.

Comment: basename does not remove the extension, just the path.

Comment: It has been so long since I looked at the man page I forgot about the SUFFIX option.

Comment: You have to know which extension you want to strip off before you know what to put in `EXT` so this is turtles all the way down. (Also, you should avoid all uppercase for your private variable names; they are reserved for system variables.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an option in `tar` to do this; did you check the man? Otherwise, you can use [Bash string expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100):

```
test="mpc-1.0.1.tar.gz"
noExt="${test/.tar.gz/}" # Remove the string '.tar.gz'
echo $noExt
```

Comment: cd $(tar tf $1 | sed -n 1p)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make dir more useful (in the case a local file with no path is specified as input) I did the following:

```
# Substring from 0 thru pos of filename
dir="${fullpath:0:${#fullpath} - ${#filename}}"
if [[ -z "$dir" ]]; then
    dir="./"
fi
```

This allows you to do something useful like add a suffix to the input file basename as:

```
outfile=${dir}${base}_suffix.${ext}

testcase: foo.bar
dir: "./"
base: "foo"
ext: "bar"
outfile: "./foo_suffix.bar"

testcase: /home/me/foo.bar
dir: "/home/me/"
base: "foo"
ext: "bar"
outfile: "/home/me/foo_suffix.bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sed 's/^/./' | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev | cut -c2-
```

to get file name and

```
sed 's/^/./' | rev | cut -d. -f1  | rev
```

to get extension.

Test case:

```
echo "filename.gz"     | sed 's/^/./' | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev | cut -c2-
echo "filename.gz"     | sed 's/^/./' | rev | cut -d. -f1  | rev
echo "filename"        | sed 's/^/./' | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev | cut -c2-
echo "filename"        | sed 's/^/./' | rev | cut -d. -f1  | rev
echo "filename.tar.gz" | sed 's/^/./' | rev | cut -d. -f2- | rev | cut -c2-
echo "filename.tar.gz" | sed 's/^/./' | rev | cut -d. -f1  | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `sed` solution that extracts path components in a variety of forms and can handle most edge cases:

```
## Enter the input path and field separator character, for example:
## (separatorChar must not be present in inputPath)

inputPath="/path/to/Foo.bar"
separatorChar=":"

## sed extracts the path components and assigns them to output variables

oldIFS="$IFS"
IFS="$separatorChar"
read dirPathWithSlash dirPath fileNameWithExt fileName fileExtWithDot fileExt <<<"$(sed -En '
s/^[[:space:]]+//
s/[[:space:]]+$//
t l1
:l1
s/^([^/]|$)//
t
s/[/]+$//
t l2
:l2
s/^$/filesystem\/\
filesystem/p
t
h
s/^(.*)([/])([^/]+)$/\1\2\
\1\
\3/p
g
t l3
:l3
s/^.*[/]([^/]+)([.])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/\1\
\2\3\
\3/p
t
s/^.*[/](.+)$/\1/p
' <<<"$inputPath" | tr "\n" "$separatorChar")"
IFS="$oldIFS"

## Results (all use separatorChar=":")

## inputPath        = /path/to/Foo.bar
## dirPathWithSlash = /path/to/
## dirPath          = /path/to 
## fileNameWithExt  = Foo.bar
## fileName         = Foo
## fileExtWithDot   = .bar
## fileExt          = bar

## inputPath        = /path/to/Foobar
## dirPathWithSlash = /path/to/
## dirPath          = /path/to 
## fileNameWithExt  = Foobar
## fileName         = Foobar
## fileExtWithDot   =
## fileExt          =

## inputPath        = /path/to/...bar
## dirPathWithSlash = /path/to/
## dirPath          = /path/to 
## fileNameWithExt  = ...bar
## fileName         = ..
## fileExtWithDot   = .bar
## fileExt          = bar

## inputPath        = /path/to/..bar
## dirPathWithSlash = /path/to/
## dirPath          = /path/to 
## fileNameWithExt  = ..bar
## fileName         = .
## fileExtWithDot   = .bar
## fileExt          = bar

## inputPath        = /path/to/.bar
## dirPathWithSlash = /path/to/
## dirPath          = /path/to 
## fileNameWithExt  = .bar
## fileName         = .bar
## fileExtWithDot   = 
## fileExt          = 

## inputPath        = /path/to/...
## dirPathWithSlash = /path/to/
## dirPath          = /path/to 
## fileNameWithExt  = ...
## fileName         = ...
## fileExtWithDot   =
## fileExt          =

## inputPath        = /path/to/Foo.
## dirPathWithSlash = /path/to/
## dirPath          = /path/to 
## fileNameWithExt  = Foo.
## fileName         = Foo.
## fileExtWithDot   =
## fileExt          =

## inputPath        = / (the root directory)
## dirPathWithSlash = filesystem/
## dirPath          = filesystem
## fileNameWithExt  =
## fileName         =
## fileExtWithDot   =
## fileExt          =

## inputPath        =  (invalid because empty)
## dirPathWithSlash =
## dirPath          =
## fileNameWithExt  =
## fileName         =
## fileExtWithDot   =
## fileExt          =

## inputPath        = Foo/bar (invalid because doesn't start with a forward slash)
## dirPathWithSlash =
## dirPath          =
## fileNameWithExt  =
## fileName         =
## fileExtWithDot   =
## fileExt          =
```

Here's how it works:

**`sed`** parses the input path and prints the following path components in order on separate lines:

- directory path with a trailing slash character
- directory path without a trailing slash character
- file name with extension
- file name without extension
- file extension with a leading dot character
- file extension without a leading dot character

**`tr`** converts the **`sed`** output into a separator character-delimited string of the above path components.

**`read`** uses the separator character as the field separator (`IFS="$separatorChar"`) and assigns each of the path components to its respective variable.

Here's how the **`sed`** construct works:

- **`s/^[[:space:]]+//`** and **`s/[[:space:]]+$//`** strip any leading and/or trailing whitespace characters
- **`t l1`** and **`:l1`** refreshes the `t` function for the next `s` function
- **`s/^([^/]|$)//`** and **`t`** tests for an invalid input path (one that does not begin with a forward slash), in which case it leaves all output lines blank and quits the `sed` command
- **`s/[/]+$//`** strips any trailing slashes
- **`t l2`** and **`:l2`** refreshes the `t` function for the next `s` function
- **`s/^$/filesystem\/\\[newline]filesystem/p`** and **`t`** tests for the special case where the input path consists of the root directory **/**, in which case it prints **filesystem/** and **filesystem** for the **dirPathWithSlash** and **dirPath** output lines, leaves all other output lines blank, and quits the *sed* command
- **`h`** saves the input path in the hold space
- **`s/^(.*)([/])([^/]+)$/\1\2\\[newline]\1\\[newline]\3/p`** prints the **dirPathWithSlash**, **dirPath**, and **fileNameWithExt** output lines
- **`g`** retrieves the input path from the hold space
- **`t l3`** and **`:l3`** refreshes the `t` function for the next `s` function
- **`s/^.*\[/]([^/]+)([.])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/\1\\[newline]\2\3\\[newline]\3/p`** and **`t`** prints the **fileName**, **fileExtWithDot**, and **fileExt** output lines for the case where a file extension exists, (assumed to consist of alphanumeric characters only), then quits the `sed` command
- **`s/^.*\[/](.+)$/\1/p`** prints the **fileName** but not the **fileExtWithDot**, and **fileExt** output lines for the case where a file extension does not exist, then quits the `sed` command.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
echo {} | grep -Eo "\w+$" # alphanumeric characters
```

or

```bash
echo {} | grep -Eo "[a-z]+$" # just lower case characters
```

or

```bash
echo {} | grep -Eo "[^.]+$" # any character outside the "."
```

or

```bash
echo {} | grep -Eo "\w+\.\w+$" # last two segments e.g. test.ts
# and so on
```

Imo, this approach is worth a mention because using [grep extended regex](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html) to match against the last segment(s) a.k.a extension is simple but effective. Note the `$` symbol denoting the end of the pattern/path.

Answer (score 0):

Funfact: if you convert `.` to `/`, basename thinks the extension is the filename.

```
basename "`tr . / <<< "$filename"`"
```

Kind of silly, but short. Variable expansion is better though.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use a `for` loop and `tr` to extract the filename from the path...

```
for x in `echo $path | tr "/" " "`; do filename=$x; done
```

The `tr` replaces all "*/*" delimiters in path with spaces so making a list of strings, and the `for` loop scans through them leaving the last one in the `filename` variable.

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, save yourself some forks and instead use: `(IFS=/ ; for x in $path; do filename=$x; done)`. The `(...)` subshell is needed to localize the assignment to IFS.

Answer (score -2):

A simple bash one liner. I used this to remove **rst** extension from all files in **pwd**

```
for each in `ls -1 *.rst`
do
     a=$(echo $each | wc -c)
     echo $each | cut -c -$(( $a-5 )) >> blognames
done
```

What it does ?

1) `ls -1 *.rst` will list all the files on stdout in new line (try).

2) `echo $each | wc -c` counts the number of characters in each filename .

3) `echo $each | cut -c -$(( $a-5 ))` selects up to last 4 characters, i.e, `.rst`.