# How to remove file extention in bash shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell

I have temp.tar.gz in $1
How do I get just 'temp' in another variable ?

I am using bash.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash

Answer (score 6):

Use [bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
echo ${1%%.*}
```

Comment: Or more specifically `${1%.tar.gz}`

Comment: @tripleee yes if we are sure that the file name ends with .tar.gz

Comment: if you know the extension, `$(basename $1 .tar.gz)` also works.

Comment: @jedwards I don't want to create a new process for such simple case.

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`

```
echo ${string%%.*}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash` and GNU `parallel`:

```
$ myFilename=`find . -maxdepth 1 -name *.gz -print0 | parallel -0 echo {.} | parallel -0 echo {.}`
$ echo $myFilename
./temp
```

Not as clean as the other approaches, for sure, but it will work with filenames with spaces in them.