# Bash parameter expansion and filename

Tags: bash, fedora

I'm trying to use the recipe found in a comment on

[Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Namely, for

```
file="example.tar.gz"
```

I'm trying to do

```
echo "${file#.*}"
```

and

```
echo "${file##.*}"
```

but both return

```
example.tar.gz
```

as opposed to what's written in that comment (tar.gz and gz respectively).

Fedora 16 GNU bash, version 4.2.20(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Shall I file a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is ${file#*.} and ${file##*.} - i.e. '*.', not '.*'  The deletion is from the left, so you want it to stop at the full stop (whereas in your case it is looking for a . at the beginning of the string and failing).  See [this article on bash string operators](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8919) for a very good and succinct explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh sorry. Mixed up the position of the dot and the asterisk. Closing as the question is incorrect.