# linux shell script: getting filename from a user input string

Tags: linux, string, shell, scripting, substring

I would like to write a shell script in which I'll take a line input from user,which will contain some xxx.cpp as filename.
I want to get that "xxx" in another variable.
e.g.

if user give input as:

```
some params path/to/file/xyz.cpp more p/ara/ms
```

I want to get xyz which occurs before".cpp" and after last occurance of "/" before ".cpp"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract filename and extension in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Comment: What if the input is "cp/b.cpp/a.cpp.f.cpp/ foo.cpp cpp/cpp.cpp/b.cpp"  You need to clarify what you are asking for.

Comment: It'll not happen..
user will give only one ***.cpp filename

Answer (score 1):

Use `basename [param] [.ext]`.

```
echo `basename $1 .cpp`
```

where 1 is the index of `path/to/file.xyz` in the argument list.

Comment: I do not get meaning of "index of"..?

if I give the input as:
[ some params path/to/file/xyz.cpp more p/ara/ms ]
what will be the index and how to get it?

Comment: @NDThokare, if it is the complete command-line, where some is the program to run then index of `some` is 0, index of `params` is 1 and index of `path/to/file/xyz.cpp` is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample bash script to prompt the user for a list of files and filter all the input and display only the base name of files that end in '.cpp' (with .cpp removed) and which are readable

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter list of files:
read list_of_files
for file in $(echo $list_of_files); do
    if echo $file | grep '\.cpp$' > /dev/null; then
        if [[ -r $file ]]; then
            fn=$(basename ${file})
            fn=${fn%.*}
            echo $fn
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: if I run this script, its not taking any input at command line.
I want to read input from user and use it to extract filename.

Comment: Ok I fixed it so it would prompt you for input instead of using the arguments to the script