# Bash How reuse found files name?

Tags: bash

I want to run a script in a directory in order to generate an svg file for each found dot file. Something like:

```
find . -name "*.dot" -exec dot -Tsvg \{} \;
```

This works fine but just output the result on stdout. usually I am using a redirection to generate the svg file. How can I get the dot file name to use it in the redirection like

```
find . -name "*.dot" -exec dot -Tsvg > "$dotfilename".svg \{} \;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following:

```
for i in `find . -name "*.dot"`; do
   dot -Tsvg $i > $i.svg
done
```

performs the find (in backticks) and loops over the results, executing `dot` for each one. The filename is in `$i`.

This uses [backtick substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) and is a useful mechanism for capturing command output for subsequent use in another command.

To remove the extension and add another, use `${i%.*}.svg`. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash) for more info.

Comment: Many thanks. In addition is it easily possible to remove the .dot extension from the svg file ?

Comment: Granted. Has some limitations

Answer (score 5):

You don't need output redirection. Use -O to save to a file whose name is automatically created from the input file name and the output format.

```
find . -name "*.dot" -exec dot -Tsvg -O \{} \;
```

Just to point out that you can use {} multiple times in the argument to -exec:

```
find . -name "*.dot" -exec dot -Tsvg -o \{}.svg \{} \;
```

Where the first would produce "foo.svg" from "foo.dot", the second would produce "foo.dot.svg"

Answer (score 2):

You can't do the redirection here. `find` does execute using `execvp(3)` or friends, not the shell. Instead, use shell globs, or make a script which you then can call from `find`

An example:

```
for i in ./*.dot
do
    svg=${i%.dot}.svg
    dot -Tsvg "$i" > "$svg"
done
```

Comment: In bash v4 you can use globstar to get recursion from the glob.

Comment: Yah. I don't want that crap (apart from the fact that it depends on bash). I prefer fixing my file organization should there ever be need.

Answer (score 2):

The problem that you are having is that redirection is processed before the find command. You can work around this by spawning another bash process in the -exec call. This also makes it easy to remove the extension using parameter expansion.

```
find . -name "*.dot" -exec bash -c 'dot -Tsvg "$1" > "${1%.*}".svg' -- {} \;
```