# Rename every unicode file of a linux directory in ascii

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to rename all unicode files name in ASCII.

I wanted to do something like this :

```
for file in `ls | egrep -v ^[a-z0-9\._-]+$`; do mv "$file" $(echo "$file" | slugify); done
```

But it doesn't work yet.

- first, regexp `^[a-z0-9\._-]+$` doesn't seem to be enough.
- second, slugify also transform the extension of the file so I have to cut the extension first and after put it back.

Any idea of a way to do that ?

Comment: you need to be more specific. Are you trying to rename all names with characters outside of ISO-646? ISO-8859-1? read 'man basename' for disassembling extensions.

Comment: I think this question is more appropriate for [Unix & Linux forum](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing first, don't parse the output of `ls`. That is, in general, a bad idea, especially if you're expecting files that have any sort of strange characters in their names.

Assuming `slugify` does what you want with filenames in general, try:

```
for file in * ; do
  if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    ext=${file##*.}
    name=${file%.*}
    new_name=$(echo "$name"|slugify)
    if [[ $name != $new_name ]] ; then
      echo mv -v "$name.$ext" "$new_name.$ext"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Warning: this will fail if you have files without an extension (it'll double-up the filename). See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1403489/635608) by [Doctor J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171236/doctor-j) if you need to handle that.

Comment: The slugify command is available with `pip install slugify` here : https://github.com/zacharyvoase/slugify