# Vim programmatically save with different file extension

Tags: bash, vim

I'm writing slim files in Vim and I want them to compile and save as html files when I save. Adding this to my .vimrc makes it happen for files in the current directory:

`au BufWritePost *.slim silent !slimrb % > $(echo % | cut -d'.' -f1).html`

It doesn't work for files with a path like `../file.slim` since the cut command turns it into
`./file.slim`.

I need to use [parameter expansions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/659910) but the % character is reserved for the current filepath when executing an external command in Vim.

How do I compile and save a slim file to a html file regardless of the directory of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
au BufWritePost *.slim :silent call system('slimrb '.shellescape(expand('%')).' > '.shellescape(expand('%:r').'.html'))
```

. In gvim with filenames not containing special characters this works just like `silent !slimrb % > %:r.html`, but in terminal vim it does not blank the screen (`silent` does not prevent this) and works when filenames contain any special character except newline. To handle newline you have to use the following:

```
au BufWritePost *.slim :execute 'silent !slimrb' shellescape(@%, 1) '>' shellescape(expand('%:r').'.html', 1) | redraw!
```

or write custom `shellescape` function.

Answer (score 1):

I realized I can trim the extension in Vim using `%:r`. To auto-compile and save a slim file as an html file I use

`au BufWritePost *.slim silent !slimrb % > %:r.html`

Comment: Now try to do the same when filename contains space, dollar, quote, any other shell special symbol. What you need to do here is `au BufWritePost *.slim :silent call system('slimrb '.shellescape(expand('%')).' > '.shellescape(expand('%:r').'.html'))`. By the way, you can pass percent sign to shell, you just have to escape it with slash (when using `:execute`+`shellescape()`: with `shellescape(str, 1)`, note the second argument) or use `system()` which does not treat this sign in any special way.

Comment: This seems like a much better solution. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.