# How to copy files to a particular folder where i have the filenames inside a file?

Tags: linux, shell

I am using linux, I have a file containing nearly 90 filenames of files from various locations in my HDD. I want to copy those files to a USB drive, how could i do that? The file containing filenames is in the following format :

```
file1
file2 
. 
. 
.
filen
```

I think a shell script could do that easily , but since i'm a beginner I don't know how to write it. Please provide a solution.

Comment: Would this solution help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355176/shell-script-to-copy-files-from-one-location-to-another-location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to know the path to the usb drive.   Then the copy command looks like

```
cp somefile tolocation
```

you'd need to put this in a loop that read the file

```
while read line
do
    echo $line;
    echo "do your copy here, for example cp $line /tmp/"
done < "yourfile"
```