# Batch Files Rename sorted by date

Tags: shell

I have folders I upload files to, with 1,000-20,000 files of different kinds (pdf, jpg, wmv...etc) with different file names and lengths with spaces in the names, etc.

I am trying make a script to rename them on a regular basis, but I want them sorted by "oldest date first", and the new name will be in the format of YYYT000001.xxxx ...  YYYY036242.xxxx (where YYYY is a fixed text "Jan" or Dec" (I will enter it manually in the script), and xxxx is the original file extension).

I've tried to use the input `for i in $(ls -tr)` as it will be sorted by oldest date, and tried to replace the file names using `basename $i`, etc.

I have searched the net but my thick head could not come up with a working script.

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using what they say in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash) and [this blog post](http://jonathanwagner.net/2007/04/zero-padding-in-bash/), you just move the file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
prefix="YYY"
i=0
for file in $(ls -tr)
do
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    paddedIndex=$(printf "%06d" $i)
    mv $file ${prefix}${paddedIndex}.${extension}
    i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

Comment: awesome, it worked, but it can not handle spaces in the old file name.. many thanks "desert69"

Comment: @LoLo `while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line"; done <<< $(ls -rt files/)`