# Bash script: remove extension from file name

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following bash script:

```
tar -zxvf $1
cd $1
```

It should extract the archive file and enter the directory that was created. Typically, package archive file creates directory with the same name, as the file, without extension, for example, mpc-1.0.1.tar.gz creates mpc-1.0.1 directory. How can I change the line `cd $1` to get directory name? Archive files have several extensions: tar.gz, tat.xz, tar.bz2.