# Change file extension name in Unix script

Tags: file, unix, replace, sed, scripting

If I have something like this:

```
file=abcdefg.url
echo $file
```

is there a way I can make it so that when I export using `>` I can export it to an html file by substituting the `.url` with a null character and appending `.html`?

for example:

```
x=(sed -n 's/URL=//p' $f) 
$out=$file.html
//replace .url with a null here
$x>$out
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash script: remove extension from file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703318/bash-script-remove-extension-from-file-name)

Answer (score -1):

Something like this...

```
out=`echo file.url | sed 's/\..*//'`.html
$x>$out
```

or (as I am learning) a better way is:

```
out=$(echo file.url | see 's\..*//').html
```

Comment: You should not use old back ticks, change to parentheses. `out=$(echo file.url | sed 's/\..*//').html`

Comment: @JohnC I didn't downvote, but read somewhere that this is the anal way to discourage duplicate content.

Answer (score -1):

You want to rename the file whose name is in `$file` from `something.url` to `something.html`, right?

If so, and assuming your shell is `bash`, you may want to use `bash` suffix removal in this way:

```
x=(sed -n 's/URL=//p' $f) 
$out=${file%\.url}.html
$x>$out
```

It should remove the `.url` suffix from the string contained by `$file`.

`man bash` for more details about it.