# Shell Script Move files with same name

Tags: shell

I want to make a shell script to run periodically to check and move my video files if they have subtitles associated

Kind of like this:

```
sourceDir = "/volume/mount/Videos";
destinationDir = "/volume/mount/VideosWithSubtitles";
validExtensions = ["avi", "mkv", "mp4"]

for every file in sourceDir that has a "validExtension"
check if a file with the same name but with a ".srt" extension exists
if it does, move both of them to "destinationDir"
```

I am not familiar with shell scripts, hence why I would appreciate your help.

Comment: If you need someone to code for you, a better place would be https://www.elance.com/ ... [Read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty, change to meet your need

```
destinationDir=/tmp/dest
sourceDir=/tmp/src
set -x
cd $sourceDir
for i in *.mp4 *.mkv *.avi; do  
    if [ -f "${i%.*}.srt" ]; then 
        mv $i $destinationDir
        mv ${i%.*}.srt $destinationDir
    fi
done

set +x
```

Output:

```
hvn@lappy: /tmp () $ bash myscript.sh
+ cd /tmp/src
+ for i in '*.mp4' '*.mkv' '*.avi'
+ '[' -f ghk.srt ']'
+ for i in '*.mp4' '*.mkv' '*.avi'
+ '[' -f xyz.srt ']'
+ for i in '*.mp4' '*.mkv' '*.avi'
+ '[' -f abc.srt ']'
+ mv abc.avi /tmp/dest
+ mv abc.srt /tmp/dest
+ set +x
```

read more about %.* here: 
[Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Comment: This does not account for files/folders with spaces, please quote your variables.