# Bash - extract file name and extension from a string

Tags: bash

Here is grep command:

```
grep "%SWFPATH%/plugins/" filename
```

And its output:

```
set(hotspot[hs_bg_%2].url,%SWFPATH%/plugins/textfield.swf);
set(hotspot[hs_%2].url,%SWFPATH%/plugins/textfield.swf);
url="%SWFPATH%/plugins/textfield.swf"
url="%SWFPATH%/plugins/scrollarea.swf"
alturl="%SWFPATH%/plugins/scrollarea.js"
url="%SWFPATH%/plugins/textfield.swf"
```

I'd like to generate a file containing the names of the all files in the 'plugins/' directory, that are mentioned in a certain file.

Basically I need to extract the file name and the extension from every line.
I can manage to delete any duplicates but I can't figure out how to extract the information that I need.

This would be the content of the file that I would like to get:

```
textfield.swf
scrollarea.swf
strollarea.js
```

Thanks!!!

PS: The thread "Extract filename and extension in bash (14 answers)" explains how to get filename and extension from a 'variable'. What I'm trying to achieve is extracting these from a 'file', which is completely different'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract filename and extension in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific problem

```
awk '/\/plugins\// {sub(/.*\//, ""); sub(/(\);|")?$/, "");
   arr[$0] = $0} END {for (i in arr) print arr[i]}' filename
```

Comment: the second `sub` does not work well with the first two strings

Comment: @blue, added in a different solution

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I didn't have any preblems with the second 'sub'

Comment: @RafaelGP, good to know! Blue pointed out an issue with the second `sub` in my original answer that I was able to subsequently fix, so you no longer see the issue in the latest answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Using **awk**:

```
grep "%SWFPATH%/plugins/" filename | \
awk '{ match($0, /plugins\/([^\/[:space:]]+)\.([[:alnum:]]+)/,submatch);
     print "filename:"submatch[1];
     print "extension:"submatch[2];
    }'
```

Some explanation:

the `match` function takes every line processed by `awk` (indicated by `$0`) and looks for matches to that regex. Submatches (the parts of the string that match the parts of the regex between parentheses) are saved in the array `submatch`. `print` is as straightforward as it looks, it just prints stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I get the following error "awk: line 1: syntax error at or near,"

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` to simply extract the filename and then `sed` to clean up the trailing )"; characters.

```
 awk -F/ '{print $NF}' a  | sed -e 's/);//' -e 's/"$//'
```