# Getting file names in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a script like this:

```
for html in ./templates/*.html
do
    # Here I need only the file name without extension.
done
```

How can I get only the file name without extension in the loop?

**EDIT** : I'm very new to UNIX.

Comment: The C language, or shell scripts

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract filename and extension in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`basename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename):

```
basename "$html" .html
```

---

Alternatively, a bash regular expression can be used to break the path into the directory prefix, basename, and file suffix:

```
$ [[ "/usr/share/doc/bzip2-devel-1.0.6/manual.html" =~ (.+/)?([^/]+)(\.[^/]+) ]]; echo ${BASH_REMATCH[*]}
/usr/share/doc/bzip2-devel-1.0.6/manual.html /usr/share/doc/bzip2-devel-1.0.6/ manual .html
^                                            ^                                 ^      ^
|                                            |                                 |      |
entire string                                directory                         base   suffix
```

Comment: And try `"$(basename "$html" .html)"` in case you want to use the result in another command.

Comment: This is returning me **default_template.html**

Comment: from `info basename` `If SUFFIX is specified and is identical to the end of NAME, it is removed from NAME as well.` So you need to call as @Alfe mentioned, `basename $html .html`

Answer (score 0):

To remove just the extension, and leave the path and name, use the right pattern matching operator:

```
for f in ./templates/*.html; do
    echo ${f%%.html}
done
```

The `%%` operator matches a substring starting from the right of the variable, and returns the rest. So it effectively matches and removes the suffix, which is very useful for file extensions.

So `./templates/index.html` will simply return `./templates/index`. You can add your own suffix or extension as required.

This is a little more efficient than invoking `basename` for every file, as it avoids the overhead of spawning another process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for html in ./templates/*.html
do
   echo $html|sed 's/\.[a-zA-Z]*$//g';
done
```