# How to extract a string at end of line after a specific word

Tags: bash, grep

I have different location, but they all have a pattern:

```
some_text/some_text/some_text/log/some_text.text
```

All locations don't start with the same thing, and they don't have the same number of subdirectories, but I am interested in what comes after `log/` only. I would like to extract the `.text`

edited question:

I have a lot of location:

```
/s/h/r/t/log/b.p
/t/j/u/f/e/log/k.h
/f/j/a/w/g/h/log/m.l
```

Just to show you that I don't know what they are, the user enters these location, so I have no idea what the user enters. The only I know is that it always contains `log/` followed by the name of the file.

I would like to extract the type of the file, whatever string comes after the dot

Comment: So given a file path `..../log/something.otherthing` you want `otherthing`?

Comment: look at edited question please

Comment: @fedorqui you understood my question

Comment: OK then I guess you can find the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/1983854

Answer (score 1):

> THe only i know is that it **always** contains log/ followed by the name
>   of the file.
>
> I would like to extract the type of the file, **whatever string comes
>   after the dot**

based on this requirement, this line works:

```
grep -o '[^.]*$' file
```

for your example, it outputs:

```
text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash built-in string operations. The example below will extract everything after the last dot from the input string.

```
$ var="some_text/some_text/some_text/log/some_text.text"
$ echo "${var##*.}"
text
```

Alternatively, use `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/.*\.//' <<< "$var"
text
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest way, but this will work

```
sed -e "s/.*log\///" | sed -e "s/\..*//"
```

This is the sed patterns for it anyway, not sure if you have that string in a variable, or if you're reading from a file etc.

You could also grab that text and store in a sed register for later substitution etc. All depends on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: the string is in a variable

Comment: Then it would be something like new_variable=$(echo $variable | sed -e "s/.*log\///" | sed -e "s/\..*//") ... that's in KShell ... let me try in Bash .. yep, works in both

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F'.' '{print $NF}' file
```

---

Using `sed`

```
sed 's/.*\.//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Running from the root of this structure:

```
    /s/h/r/t/log/b.p
    /t/j/u/f/e/log/k.h
    /f/j/a/w/g/h/log/m.l
```

This seems to work, you can skip the `echo` command if you really just want the file types with no record of where they came from.

```
    $ for DIR in *; do
    >  echo -n "$DIR  "
    >  find $DIR -path "*/log/*" -exec basename {} \; | sed 's/.*\.//'
    > done
    f  l
    s  p
    t  h
```