# Differentiating between file extension and hidden files beginning with a .dot

Tags: python, bash, filenames, file-extension, dotfiles

The file extension is typically everything after the last period. If a filename has no ".", it has no extension. What happens when the filename begins with a dot, as hidden files in linux do?

In python, the file has no extension...

```
>>> os.path.splitext("base.ext")
('base', '.ext')
>>> os.path.splitext(".ext")                                                                                              
('.ext', '')
```

The common method in bash produces the other result where there is only an extension and no base part ([Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash))...

```
>>> filename=".ext"
>>> extension="${filename##*.}"
>>> base="${filename%.*}"
>>> echo $base

>>> echo $extension
ext
```

How should code handle filenames such as this? Is there a standard? Does it differ per operating system? Or simply which is most common/consistent?

*[EDIT]*
Lets say you have a file that's just "`.pdf`". Should, for example, an open dialogue default to listing it without 1. showing hidden files and 2. allowing all file extensions?

1. It's a hidden file - it begins with a period
2. Is it actually a .pdf (by filename convention, sure it has pdf data) or is it a file witn *no* extension?

Answer (score 1):

File extensions in POSIX-based operating systems have no innate meaning; they're just a convention. Changing the extension wouldn't change anything about the file itself, just the name used to refer to it.

A file could have multiple extensions:

```
source.tar.gz
```

Sometimes a single extension represents a contraction of two:

```
source.tgz
```

Other files may not have an extension at all:

```
.bashrc
README
ABOUT
TODO
```

Typically, the only thing that defines an extension is that it is a trailing component of a filename that follows a non-initial period. Meaning is assigned by the application examining the file name. A PDF reader may focus on files whose names end with `.pdf`, but it should not refuse to open a valid PDF file whose name does not.

Note that

```
extension="${filename##*.}"
```

is simply an application of a parameter expansion operator which only returns the (final) extension if the filename does not start with a period. It's not an extension operator, it is a prefix-removal operator.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of these, please see the edit. In the case of `.bashrc`, it's pretty obvious that's it's the main filename, not an extension. What about `.pdf`? Going by the same rule, it should be said to have *no* extension.

Comment: Whether or not there is any required connection between the contents of a file and its extension(s) (if any) is up to the operating system. `.pdf` *seems* like an empty file name with an extension because you are familiar with the use of `.pdf` to indicate a PDF file. Ask yourself what `.udn` is: is it simply a file that starts with a period, or an extension for some data type you aren't familiar with? This is why a good dialog box allows you to display all files, or give a user-specified filter, because there is no hard rule for how files must be named.

Comment: This is exactly my point. If an open file dialogue is built with an internal split-extension function, which should the split-extension choose? I don't think it should be context sensitive.

Comment: File extensions are by definition context-sensitive. `.pdf` might be intended to be a hidden file; it might be a poorly named PDF file. There's no way to tell. Even the leading-period thing is just a convention; there's nothing special about the file itself. Programs like `ls` simply ignore them unless instructed otherwise.

Comment: One final comment:  a period doesn't even necessarily indicate an extension: OS X plist files have names like `com.apple.ActivityMonitor.plist`. Only the `plist` component is considered an extension; everything preceding it is a dotted file name which is interpreted as a hierarchical description of who is responsible for creating the file and which program uses it.

Comment: Agreed. But as you say, programs like `ls` ignore them by default. So the creators have set a convention (which is not context sensitive - `.` files are ignored. always), which I'd prefer to follow. In this case it seems more and more appropriate to ignore an initial `.`, if it exists, for filename extension parsing (at least on linux).

Comment: I'd like a link to make sure that everybody is conventionally aware that initial dots in filename does not start the extension. In my sense, bash behavior is what to expect. `.bashrc` has no base name, and is a filename that is basically, just an extension. How does boost::filesystem copes with that ?