# Regex with sed to parse archive name

Tags: regex, sed

I'd like to parse different kinds of Java archive with the `sed` command line tool.

Archives can have the followin extensions:
`.jar`, `.war`, `.ear`, `.esb`

What I'd like to get is the name without the extension, e.g. for `Foobar.jar` I'd like to get `Foobar`.

This seems fairly simple, but I cannot come up with a solution that works and is also robust.

I tried something along the lines of `sed s/\.+(jar|war|ear|esb)$//`, but could not make it work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract filename and extension in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there:

```
sed -E 's/\.+(jar|war|ear|esb)$//' file
```

Just needed to add the `-E` flag to sed to interpret the expression. And of course, respect the `sed 's/something/new/'` syntax.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
aaa.jar
bb.war
hello.ear
buuu.esb
hello.txt

$ sed -E 's/\.+(jar|war|ear|esb)$//' a
aaa
bb
hello
buuu
hello.txt
```

Comment: You also need to add the quotes `'` not only `-E` :)

Comment: Errr yes haha, true :)

Comment: It can even be shorten some: `sed -E 's/\.+([jew]ar|esb)$//'`

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
s='Foobar.jar'
sed -r 's/\.(jar|war|ear|esb)$//' <<< "$s"
Foobar
```

OR *better do it in BASH itself*:

```
echo "${s/.[jwe]ar/}"
Foobar
```

Comment: The last one is quite elegant, but doesn't match `esb`. Also, you can use the `${parameter%word}` syntax to only strip the ending of a name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `|` and the `()` and also add `'` if you do not add option like `-r` or `-E`

```
echo "test.jar" | sed 's/\.\(jar\|war\|ear\|esb\)$//'
test
```

`*` is also not needed, sine you normal have only one `.`

Answer (score 0):

On traditionnal UNIX (tested with AIX/KSH)

```
File='Foobar.jar'
echo ${File%.*}
```

from a list having only your kind of file

```
YourList | sed 's/\....$//'
```

form a list of all kind of file

```
YouList | sed -n 's/\.[jew]ar$/p
t
s/\.esb$//p'
```