# How to copy multiple files and rename them at once by appending a string in between the file names in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a few files that I want to copy and rename with the new file names generated by adding a fixed string to each of them. 
E.g:

```
ls -ltr | tail -3
games.txt
files.sh
system.pl
```

Output should be:

```
games_my.txt
files_my.sh
system_my.pl
```

I am able to append at the end of file names but not before *.txt.

```
for i in `ls -ltr | tail -10`; do cp $i `echo $i\_my`;done
```

I am thinking if I am able to save the extension of each file by a simple cut as follows,

```
ext=cut -d'.' -f2
```

then I can append the same in the above for loop.

```
do cp $i `echo $i$ext\_my`;done
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
for file in *
do
   name="${file%.*}"
   extension="${file##*.}"
   cp $file ${name}_my${extension}
done
```

Note that `${file%.*}` returns the file name without extension, so that from `hello.txt` you get `hello`. By doing `${file%.*}_my.txt` you then get from `hello.txt` -> `hello_my.txt`.

Regarding the extension, `extension="${file##*.}"` gets it. It is based on the question [Extract filename and extension in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/1983854).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the file names are of different extensions and I want to retain the respective extension of each file with the rename.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I don't exactly get what file%.* and file##*. are doing? What does % and ## do in this case?

Comment: `${file##*.}` removes everything before last `.`, so that you get the extension. `${file%.*}` returns everything before last `.`, so that you get the file name without extension. You can check http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

If the shell variable expansion mechanisms provided by fedorqui's answer look too unreadable to you, you also can use the unix tool `basename` with a second argument to strip off the suffix:

```
for file in *.txt
do
  cp -i "$file" "$(basename "$file" .txt)_my.txt"
done
```

Btw, in such cases I always propose to apply the `-i` option for `cp` to prevent any unwanted overwrites due to typing errors or similar.

It's also possible to use a direct replacement with shell methods:

```
  cp -i "$file" "${file/.txt/_my.txt}"
```

The ways are numerous :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the file names are of different extensions and I want to retain the respective extension of each file with the rename

Comment: You could use `"${file/./_my.}"` then.  It replaces just the `.` with `_my.`, so the extension stays untouched and intact.  But you need to be sure then that there only is exactly one dot in the file name.