# append string to file name when string is missing

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm trying to append a string into a file name , each time that string is missing.

Example :

I have

```
idbank.xls
idbank.xls
idbank.xls
```

I'm looking for the string

```
codegroup
```

As the string does not exist, I'm appending it to the file name before the extension. 
The required output will be

```
idbankxxxcodeGroupea1111.xls
idbankxxxcodeGroupea1111.xls
idbankxxxcodeGroupea1111.xls
```

I made this script (see below) but it is not working properly

```
for file in idbank*.xls; do
 if $(ls | grep -v 'codeGroupe' $file); then
  printf '%s\n' "${f%.xls}codeGroupea1111.xls"
 fi; done
```

The grep -v is to check if the string is here or not. I read on a different post that you can use the option -q but in checking the man , it says it is for silent...

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Best

Comment: So you want to rename those files based on this condition?

Comment: Yes , Fedorqui. If the string `codeGroupe` does not exist in the filename.

Comment: `-q` silences the output, so you can simply say `if grep -q ...`; then`, and let the exit status of `grep` control the `if` statement without having to actually see the output.

Comment: I want to see the output actually, Chepner.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from `idbank.xls` to `xxxcodeGroupea1111.xls`. Where did the `xxx` come from? Where did the `idbank` go? Also, it's not possible for a single directory to have multiple files all named `idbank.xls`.

Comment: Ruakh, I meant `idbankxxxcodeGroupea1111.xls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can make it:

```
for file in idbank*xls
do
  [[ $file != *codegroup* ]] && mv $file ${file%.*}codegroup.${file##*.}
done
```

- The `for file` is what you are already using.
- `[[ $file != *codegroup* ]]` checks if the file name contains `codegroup` or not.
- If not, `mv $file ${var%.*}codegroup.${var##*.}` is performed: it renames the file by moving it to `filename_without_extension` + `codgroup` + `extension` (further reference in [Extract filename and extension in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/1983854)).

---

Note

```
[[ $file != *codegroup* ]] && mv $file ${file%.*}codegroup.${file##*.}
```

Is the same as:

```
if [[ $file != *codegroup* ]]; then
  mv $file ${file%.*}codegroup.${file##*.}
fi
```

Comment: "filename without extension" would be `"${file%.*}"` with only one "%"

Comment: You are completely right, thanks @glennjackman for letting me now

Comment: Thanks Fedorqui. Both works fine. Thanks for all the explanation. I note them down.