# How to cut and limit a string size at the same time?

Tags: python, string, slice

Here is an example of what i need.

Suppose that we have the following string:

```
str = "/home/user/folder/MyVeryLongFileName.foo"
```

I have multiple operations to do on this one :

1. remove the path (assuming i have its length) :

   ```
   str = str[path_length:]
   ```
2. revome the extension (always 4 char in my case) :

   ```
   str = str[path_length:-4]
   ```

   So, right now my string looks like `MyVeryLongFileName`
3. Now I would like to limit its size at 15 characters.
   Is it possible to do it in the same expression ? Or may I have to do it after the 2 previous operations ?

Comment: What do you mean by limiting to 15? Only first 15 characters should be allowed?

Comment: Chances are you want to import os.path instead of string operations.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html -- particularly https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only the first 15 characters, then you can slice the string again, like this:

```
file_name[path_length:-4][:15]
```

If you really are dealing with filenames, you might want to go with

```
>>> file_name = "/home/user/folder/MyVeryLongFileName.foo"
>>> import os
>>> print os.path.split(file_name)[1].rpartition(".")[0][:15]
MyVeryLongFileN
```

Or:

```
>>> print os.path.basename(file_name).rpartition(".")[0][:15]
'MyVeryLongFileN'
```

Also, it would be better to use `splitext` to get the extension, like this

```
>>> from os.path import basename, splitext
>>> print splitext(basename(file_name))[0][:15]
MyVeryLongFileN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the filename with this:

```
>>> print str.split('/')[-1]
MyVeryLongFileName.foo
```

Remove the extension with:

```
>>> print str.split('.')[0]
/home/user/folder/MyVeryLongFileName
```

Limit the file name to 15 characters:

```
>>> print str.split('/')[-1][:15]
MyVeryLongFileN
```

---

This being said, you can always use the bash utils to extract this info. `basename` is the tool to get the file and `dirname` to get the path. See [Extract filename and extension in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash) for more info.

Comment: I don't get why you suggest to use bash's `basename` and `dirname` (when the OP never mentioned bash nor tagged the question with the tag) when your python code doesn't use them (since they are available as `os.path.basename`, `os.path.dirname`). Your answer is certainly inferior to all other answers to this question and it's suggesting a *bad* solution to the problem (because it's OS specific and fails in certain situations).

Comment: @Bakuriu well I intentionally placed a <hr> above the extra information, because it was a different approach. I agree there can be other ways, even better, but having a path with normal slashes `/` gives idea that we are in a *NIX environment. Feel free to suggest improvements so that we can all learn.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
>>> from os.path import splitext, basename
>>> apath = "/home/user/folder/MyVeryLongFileName.foo"
>>> splitext(basename(apath))[0][:15]
'MyVeryLongFileN'
```

`splitext` separates the file-extension from the rest, and we do this on the result of `basename` which splits the part into the base file-name and the rest of the path. Then we can cut down the remaining string. I would definitely use these methods because they are much more reliable.