# Parsing a job name out of a server log

Tags: bash, parsing, unix

The log output lines look like follows

> HLGAPL65.HOU150.CHEVRONTEXACO.NET/UPSTREAM_MDM_D2/Jobs/Keystone
>   Release 2.0.2.0/0.0. Loading_SOR_to_Landing/EGI/EGI_WV_WELLHDR.pjb

I need to extract the name that appears right after the last "/" and before the ".pjb"

In this particular case - the needed name is EGI_WV_WELLHDR.

What is the most efficient and simple way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`, run the following:

```
sed -r 's/.*\/([^\/]+)\.pjb/\1/g' logfile
```

Comment: Hold on. The initial answer fitted my purpose better :)

Comment: How do I make the regexp start one slash earlier?

Comment: sed -r 's/.*\/([^\/]+\/[^\/]+)\.pjb/\1/g' logfile

Comment: Thanks! One lost plea :) Is it possible to make this regexp start from the 3rd slash to the left?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk`:

```
$ awk -F"[/.]" '{print $(NF-1)}' file
EGI_WV_WELLHDR
```

#### Explanation

- `-F"[/.]"` sets delimiter as dot or slash.
- `{print $(NF-1)}` prints the penultimate field based on those field separators.

---

If what you want is the filename without extension, then you can do the following:

- Get the last field in the line, which is the full path of the file.
- Get the file name as described in [Extract filename and extension in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/1983854)

See:

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' file
Loading_SOR_to_Landing/EGI/EGI_WV_WELLHDR.pjb
$ t=$(basename $(awk '{print $NF}' a))
$ echo "$t"
EGI_WV_WELLHDR.pjb
$ echo ${t%.*}
EGI_WV_WELLHDR
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this sed command,

```
$ sed -r 's/^.*\/([^.]*)\.pjb$/\1/g' file
EGI_WV_WELLHDR
```

`-r` --> Extended regex.

`^.*\/([^.]*)\.pjb$`

The above regex fetches the characters that are inbetween the last `/` and `.pjb`. Then the fetched characters in group are printed through backreference.

Comment: How do I make the regexp start one slash earlier?

Comment: did you want this `EGI/EGI_WV_WELLHDR` as output?

Comment: then try `sed -r 's/^.*\/([^.]*\/.*)\.pjb$/\1/g' file`

Answer (score 1):

using `cut` and `rev`:

```
rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | cut -d'.' -f2 | rev
```

Answer (score 0):

As your separator is a slash, you can use `basename` :

```
$ basename "HLGAPL65.HOU150.CHEVRONTEXACO.NET/UPSTREAM_MDM_D2/Jobs/Keystone Release 2.0.2.0/0.0. Loading_SOR_to_Landing/EGI/EGI_WV_WELLHDR.pjb" .pjb
EGI_WV_WELLHDR
```