# How to get filename without extension from %f in bash terminal?

Tags: bash, filenames

The below program (when-changed) gives the filename `%f` which can be used in the command. How can I get only the filename without file extension from this `%f` ?

This is the command that I want to use:

```
when-changed *.scss -c sassc %f f%-min.css
```

It saves a filename like: `layout.scss-min.css`
What I need is only `layout-min.css`, if possible.

Comment: As seen in [Extract filename and extension in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/1983854), use `filename="${filename%.*}"`.

Comment: `echo layout.scss-min.css | awk '{print substr($0,0,index($0,".")-1) substr($0,index($0,"-"))}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a little shell script that calls sassc for you, instead of calling it directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$1
outfile="${filename%.*}"  # Do your filename replacement here
sassc "$filename" "$outfile"
```

Then call:

```
 when-changed *.scss -c ./myscript.sh %f
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this on the command line. The filename is not really put in the `%f` variable on the command line. Instead, you pass `%f` to when-changed and when-changed itself replaces it with the filename.

Change the [source of when-changed](https://github.com/joh/when-changed/blob/master/whenchanged/whenchanged.py#L32) to do what you want. For example, change this part:

```
def run_command(self, file):
    os.system(self.command.replace('%f', file))
```

To this:

```
def run_command(self, file):
    command = self.command
    command = command.replace('%f', file)
    command = command.replace('%c', file.replace('.scss', ''))
    os.system(command)
```