# Appending a string before file extension in Bash script

Tags: bash

I need to add a number just before the extension of the files with a Bash script. For example, I want to convert a file name like `abc.efg` to  `abc.001.efg`. The problem is that I don't know what is the extension of the file (it is one of the parameters of the script).

I was looking for the quickest way of doing this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
extension="${file##*.}"                     # get the extension
filename="${file%.*}"                       # get the filename
mv "$file" "${filename}001.${extension}"    # rename file by moving it
```

You can see more info about these commands in the excellent answer to [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/1983854).

#### Test

```
$ ls hello.*
hello.doc  hello.txt
```

Let's rename these files:

```
$ for file in hello*; do ext="${file##*.}"; filename="${file%.*}"; mv "$file" "${filename}001.${ext}"; done
```

Now check whether renaming worked as expected:

```
$ ls hello*
hello001.doc  hello001.txt
```

Comment: +1 this is the right way, alas BASH doesn't let you combine 2 operations into one.

Comment: Thanks ;) We could try to trick it a little bit to make it almost one-liner, but I think it is more clear to do it step by step.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 's/\.[^.]*$/.001&/'
```

you can build your `mv` cmd with above one-liner.

example:

```
kent$  echo "abc.bar.blah.hello.foo"|sed 's/\.[^.]*$/.001&/' 
abc.bar.blah.hello.001.foo
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file extension is in a variable EXT, and your file is in a variable FILE, then something like this should work

```
EXT=ext;FILE=file.ext;echo ${FILE/%$EXT/001.$EXT}
```

This prints

```
file.001.ext
```

The substitution is anchored to the end of the string, so it won't matter if your extension appears in the filename. More info here http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html