# getting the last field of a string separated by a particular delimiter in bash

Tags: bash

I'm writing a script that copies a set of files to a directory using bash scripting. A file that I'm trying to copy might already exist in the directory so I have to rename the file to avoid replacing the original one.

For an example if I have to copy a file called "abc.dd.java" and a file with the same name already exists, I have to rename the file as "abc.dd1.java" and copy it.

If the destination contains "abc.dd.java" and "abc.dd1.java" then the file should be renamed "abc.dd2.java"

I wrote a code snippet that does that:

```
#$file contains the full path for the original file.
#$path contains the full path for the copied file.

copypath="$path"
echo "$path"
count=1
while [ -f "$path" ]
do
    part1=`echo "$copypath" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}{for(i=1;i<NF-1;i++){printf("%s.",$i)}printf("%s",$(NF-1))}END{}'`
    part2=`echo "$copypath" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="."}{printf("%s",$NF)}END{}'`
    path="$part1""$count.""$part2"
    count=`expr "$count" + 1`
done
cp "$file" "$path"
```

This does work correctly. But it seems too crude. Isn't there a better way of separating out the file extension part and the name parts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash . But watch out for files without an extension!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question has been answered in 
[Extract filename and extension in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash).

Here is a simple version which (mostly) works, based on that link:

```
part1="${copypath%.*}"            # remove file extension (shortest .* suffix)
part2="${copypath##*.}"           # remove base path (longest *. prefix)
path="${part1}${count}.${part2}"
```

And here is a more complete answer which also handles files without extensions:

```
if [[ "$copypath" =~ [^/.][.][^/.]+$ ]]
then
    # copypath has an extension
    part1="${copypath%.*}"
    part2=".${copypath##*.}"
else
    # no valid extension, so insert the number at the end
    part1="$copypath"
    part2=""
fi
path="${part1}${count}${part2}"
```

Features:

- Whitespace is handled well.
- Multiple dots are handled as requested.
  e.g. `abc.dd.java` becomes `abc.dd1.java`
- Files without an extension are handled properly.
  e.g. `file` becomes `file1`
- Dot files with no extension are also handled properly.
  e.g. `.bashrc` becomes `.bashrc1`

Caveats:

- Multiple extensions are not handled specially.
  e.g. `archive.tar.gz` becomes `archive.tar1.gz` instead of `archive1.tar.gz`
- If the part before the extension ends with a dot it is not considered to be an extension.
  e.g. `This is a sentence..txt` becomes `This is a sentence..txt2`
  To treat this as having an extension change the regular expression to `[^/][.][^/.]+$`
- Does not attempt to handle directories.
- Only tested in Bash, unlikely to work with other shells (but could be changed to use `grep`).

Answer (score 2):

To Split the filename and extention you can use the below string manipulations

```
filename="/tmp/example.txt"

# will output "txt" (extention)
echo ${filename##*.} 

# will output "/tmp/example" 
echo ${filename%%.*}
```

Comment: Test it with `"/tmp/another.example.txt"`. The second expansion should have `%` instead of `%%` (shortest match instead of longest match).

Answer (score 0):

Try if you have just .java files with something:

```
fname=$(basename file.java .java)
echo $fname
```

output:

```
file
```

and then you can do your further processing.