# how to cut directory from $file in the bash shell

Tags: shell

I'm newbie for a shell script. So I need to cut the directory name from my $file.
e.g.

`fullpath='/var/log/apache/access.log`

Now I need to cutting "apache" to output. How can I do.

Thank in advance.

Comment: You're probably looking for `basename`. Have you searched StackOverflow for similar questions? You may find your answer by just searching a little more. Here is one, for example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash/965072#965072

Comment: If it is the directory you're after, it's probably `dirname` you want.

Comment: Valid point. Though from the example, he may want just "apache", not /var/log/apache, which would be the output of dirname. In that case `basename $(dirname $FULLPATH)` would give the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combination of `basename` and `dirname` will give you the parent directory of the file you provided in `$fullpath`

For example:

```
FULLPATH=/var/log/apache/access.log; basename $(dirname $FULLPATH)
```

will print "apache"

Comment: @dimsum If this answer works for you, please check the box next to it (to select as the correct answer for your question).

Answer (score -1):

vim Filename

fullpath='/var/log/apache/access.log

then save and exit

cut -d'/' -f4 Filename

Comment: This solution isn't very helpful as the number of directories in a full path is not constant. Taking the fourth field will not always yield a filename, pathname, or anything at all.