# bash rename keep extension on file, name variable

Tags: bash

randomi have one file named image.jpg but extension can be other..

I want to rename these file using bash

keep extension but name is in contains variable.

ex

var1="cat"

var2="dog"

```
image.png -> cat.png
image.jpeg -> dog.jpeg
```

I think I should look in the folder the file named image *. *, copy the extension, and then use the variable name + extension in new name.

```
     namefinal=$random

      ext=`echo $ls image*.*`

        echo $ext
        EXTENSION=`echo "$ext" | cut -d'.' -f2`

    echo $EXTENSION

mv $ext $random.$EXTENSION
```

done!, thanks.

Comment: Where do the mappings of input name to output name come from? How do you know which file to use which name on?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash?rq=1

Comment: BTW, using `ls` in a script is almost always wrong (for reasons in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and so is `ls=/bin/ls` and then using `$ls` in place of just running `ls` (in general, for any command; the shell will automatically do that caching after its first lookup, so doing it yourself just makes your script harder to read and adds potential for bugs -- no significant performance improvement; actively makes things *slower* if you use `which` for the lookup, which has more overhead than letting the shell search the PATH itself).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `$file` contains "image.png":

```
mv "$file" "$var1.${file##*.}"
```

Comment: No one is asking you to.

Comment: @shoryunix, why do you think that information makes you unable to use this answer?