# Rename multiple files with different extensions on linux

Tags: linux, file-rename

I have a bunch of files with different extensions and i would like to add a suffix at the end of all of their names:

```
Fe2-K-D4.rac
Fe2-K-D4.plo
Fe2-K-D4_iso.xy
...
```

to

```
Fe2-K-D4-4cc8.rac
Fe2-K-D4-4cc8.plo
Fe2-K-D4-4cc8_iso.xy
...
```

I read a few posts about changing the extension using the rename tool but i don't know how to change the name and keep the same extension (I'm a recent linus user).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/1983854), I would say:

```
for file in *
do
  extension="${file##*.}"
  filename="${file%.*}"
  mv "$file" "${filename}-4cc8.${extension}"
done
```

This loops through all the files, gets its name and extension and then moves it (that is, renames it) to the given name with an extra `-4cc8` value before the extension.

Answer (score 2):

Using `rename`:

```
rename 's/[.]([^.]+)$/-4cc8.$1/' *
```

---

`s/[.]([^.]+)$/-4cc8.$1/` is a [perl expression of the form `s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)
which tells `rename` to do a global substition.

`[.]([^.]+)$` is a regex pattern with the following meaning:

```
[.]     match a literal period
(       followed by a group
  [     containing a character class
    ^.  composed of anything except a literal period  
  ]+    match 1-or-more characters from the character class
)       end group
$       match the end of the string.
```

The replacement pattern, `-4cc8.$1`, tells `rename` to replace the matched text with a literal `-4cc8.` followed by text in the first group matched, i.e. whatever followed the literal period.