# Assigning echo and cut command to a variable

Tags: bash, cut

I'm trying to get the string "boo" from "upper/lower/boo.txt" and assign it to a variable. I was trying

```
NAME= $(echo $WHOLE_THING | rev | cut -d "/" -f 1 | rev | cut -d "." -f 1)
```

but it comes out empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the syntax is `var=$(command)`. Remove the space after `=`. Also, you may find interesting [Extract filename and extension in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/1983854)

Comment: ...mind you, this is also a very silly way to do that operation.

Comment: ah I'm an idiot, thanks

what would be a better way?

Comment: (On a different point, all-caps names are reserved; you should use names with at least one lower-case character for your own variables).

Comment: BTW, http://www.shellcheck.net/ would have also found your original issue (and a few others). :)

Answer (score 7):

Don't do it that way at all. Much more efficient is to use built-in shell operations rather than out-of-process tools such as `cut` and `rev`.

```
whole_thing=upper/lower/boo.txt
name=${whole_thing##*/}
name=${name%%.*}
```

See [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for a general introduction to best practices for string manipulation in bash, or [the bash-hackers page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for a more focused reference on the techniques used here.

---

Now, in terms of why your original code didn't work:

```
var=$(command_goes_here)
```

...is the correct syntax. By contrast:

```
var= $(command_goes_here)
```

...exports an empty environment variable named `var` while running `command_goes_here`, and then while running the *output* of `command_goes_here` as its own command.

---

To show yet another variant,

```
var = command_goes_here
```

...runs `var` as a command, with `=` as its first argument, and `command_goes_here` as a subsequent argument. Which is to say, whitespace is important. :)

Comment: this great answer prompts me a question: if I say `var=3 echo "$var"`, should it return `3`? It returns nothing.

Comment: @fedorqui, ...because variables set that way are in the environment only, and not available at expansion time. Yes, that's expected behavior.

Comment: @fedorqui, ...by contrast, compare to `var=3 sh -c 'echo "$var"'`.

Comment: Oooh that's it! I was doing many tests and couldn't find the way. So let's see if I understand your solution: by saying `var=3` we define the variable in the environment, which is "copied" or "received" by the subshell we open with `sh -c`.

Comment: Right. You can also see it in the output of `var=3 env`.

Comment: Many thanks. I will try to add a question about this, so that we can move this interesting comments by you into a place where they can be better found. Will try in a couple of days.

Comment: I posted the question! [Assign and use of a variable in the same subshell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30982767/1983854).