# Assign and use of a variable in the same subshell

Tags: bash, scope, subshell

I was doing something very simple like: `v=5 echo "$v"` and expected it to print `5`. However, it does not. The value that was just set is not available for the next command.

I [recently learnt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30727654/1983854) that "*In most shells, each command of a pipeline is executed in a separate SubShell*". However, in this case both commands are being executed in the same subshell.

Why does this happen? Is there any way to have this working?

Full example:

```
$ v=1
$ v=5 echo "$v"
1                   # I expected 5!
```