# Rationale for POSIX specification for variable assignments in a shell command

Tags: shell

I've just tracked down a problem with a shell script of mine on systems like Ubuntu that use dash for /bin/sh. My script needs to pass some environment variables in when it executes a binary and, for reasons that are not relevant here, it runs the binary using eval. A cut-down version using "env" for the binary would be like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
RUNBIN=env
XYZ=abc eval $RUNBIN
```

With dash, the above fails to pass XYZ=abc into the environment when it runs env. If you play around some more you will also find that it declares XYZ as a (non-exported) shell variable for the rest of the script. I presume is down to an [issue raised on the 2008 POSIX specs](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=255) and addressed in the [2013 edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) which says:

> If no command name results *[from processing the command line]*, or if the command name is a special built-in or function, variable assignments shall affect the current execution environment. Otherwise, the variable assignments shall be exported for the execution environment of the command and shall not affect the current execution environment except as a side-effect of the expansions performed *[while doing tilde expansion and other stuff to get the command line]*

The issue is actually about the processing of a list of variable assignments and whether earlier assignments are visible in later ones, but the change in wording seems to have had an unintended side-effect of making the variable assignments completely useless if the shell built-in you run is going to execute something. You get the same problem if you do something like

```
echo 'env | grep XYZ' > t
XYZ=abc . ./t
```

which prints nothing. `bash` does what I would expect (with the last example it prints XYZ=abc. Or with `--posix` it additionally assigns (but does not export) XYZ=abc in subsequent commands. So:

```
XYZ=abc . ./t
echo XYZ=$XYZ
```

prints `XYZ=abc` twice.

I find it odd that the variable assignments persist into subsequent commands when the command is a built-in, but life is full of oddities. However it just seems plain wrong that variable assignments on a command line aren't exported into any commands the command line runs. Unfortunately `bash` and I seem to be in the minority about this - on my Mac, ksh and zsh do what dash does. It is easy enough, but inelegant, to work around this behaviour using `export` and brackets to delimit the scope of the variables. My question is why would anybody want the POSIX behaviour, especially by providing examples where it is useful in practice? Or should this be reported as a bug in POSIX?

Comment: I'm not sure than your question is covered by the [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (e.g. practical, answerable problem) - but ok, maybe someone will answer it. From my point of view, the answers will be purely opinion based.

Comment: You may find this question of some relevance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30982767/477563

Comment: @Mr.Llama: thanks, but the "problem" in that question is to do with what I described above as "*doing tilde expansion and other stuff to get the command line*" and the behaviour there is exactly what I would expect.

Answer (score 4):

*Note:* A *shell* is a somewhat nebulous term for a command line interpreter.  Each *shell* (e.g. `sh`, `bash`, `ksh`, `dash`, `tcsh`, `...`) is free to interpret things as it chooses. Some don't even have `sh`-like syntax [or semantics] at all.

However, most shells do follow the standard rules, because they tend to make the most sense. The POSIX standard *does* make sense, when broken down a bit as I'll try to do below.

---

> If no command name results *[from processing the command line]*, variable assignments shall affect the current execution environment.

This covers the following:

```
XYZ=abc
echo $XYZ
```

`XYZ` is a simple variable. It does *not* set the exported environment. This is what one would expect.

---

> if the command name is a special built-in or function, variable assignments shall affect the current execution environment.

This covers the following:

```
XYZ=abc builtin
XYZ=def myfunction
```

It is [effectively] shorthand for:

```
XYZ=abc ; builtin
XYZ=def ; myfunction
```

The reason for this is that builtins and/or functions run in the current environment and *need* access to or may modify variables there:

```
function myfunction ()
{
    XYZ=qrm$XYZ
}
```

**However ...**

`bash` (e.g.) does *not* do this by default [without `--posix`]. To implement its default behavior, `bash` must "clone" [a portion of] the environment [herein `XYZ`] for the builtin/function duration. Although, it may be technically more correct (i.e. behaves more like the external program case), it also adds complexity to the implementation.

POSIX chose the definition that leads to a simpler implementation. Also, the fact that the majority of non-bash shells were doing it one way and bash another may have influenced things.

---

> Otherwise, the variable assignments shall be exported for the execution environment of the command and shall not affect the current execution environment

This covers:

```
XYZ=abc external_program
```

The reason is that this is [effectively] shorthand for:

```
env XYZ=abc external_program
```

The behavior is easy to implement by setting `XYZ` in the child [after the `fork` and before the `execvp`], so no additional complexity [in the form of a new mechanism] is needed.

*Side note:* If you *want* to set both environments:

```
export XYZ=abc
external_program
myfunction
echo $XYZ
```

---

When we do `XYZ=abc <some_command>`, ideally we want `XYZ` to persist only for the duration of the command (i.e. that's the most useful model).

For an external, this is easy enough, as explained above.

But, for an internal, the only way to do this is to modify the current environment. Otherwise, builtins and functions can't work correctly. So, the changes must persist after the command is executed [*Exception:* `bash` as noted above].

---

So, if you are using a shell that doesn't quite follow the above POSIX rules, you can [probably] guarantee the effect you want by explicitly using the "shorthand" versions above [or whatever special shell specific sequence you need].

---

Personally, I *dislike* allowing `XYZ=abc <command_of_any_sort>` at *all*. If you want this, do `env XYZ=abc <command>` or `XYZ=abc ; myfunction`. IMO, the "compound" version is just needless cruft that requires that one learn "yet another [minor] thing" ...

That's [just] my opinion. Obviously, there are others.

POSIX has to balance opinion, known current implementations, lack of spec clarity, etc.

So, is POSIX broken? In this instance, it has specific, well defined behavior. So, probably, the answer is no, even if there are [arguably] better ways to do it.

---

**UPDATE:**

Per your comment, take heart. There is a way to get the results for a builtin/function *without* resorting to `eval`.

Upon further thought, I *dislike* the default `bash` behavior for two reasons.

First and foremost, it's non-standard [not POSIX compliant]. So, it's the "odd duck".

Secondly, there is a *clean* way to get the `bash` *behavior* if one so desires [in a posix compliant shell], by using scoped `local` variables. Essentially, this is what `bash` was doing anyway (i.e. injecting the variable into the function's scoped environment).

Here are four ways to get the `bash` equivalent behavior [albeit with a bit more setup]:

```
#!/bin/sh -

myfnc () {
    XYZ=myf$XYZ
    echo "myfnc: XYZ=$XYZ"
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bashlike1 () {
    local XYZ
    echo
    echo "bashlike1: ..."
    XYZ=def myfnc
}

XYZ="abc"
bashlike1
echo "parent: XYZ=$XYZ"

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bashlike2 () {
    local XYZ="def"
    echo
    echo "bashlike2: ..."
    $1
}

XYZ="abc"
bashlike2 myfnc
echo "parent: XYZ=$XYZ"

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bashlike3 () {
    local $1
    echo
    echo "bashlike3: ..."
    $2
}

XYZ="abc"
bashlike3 "XYZ=def" myfnc
echo "parent: XYZ=$XYZ"

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bashlike4 () {
    $1
    echo
    echo "bashlike4: ..."
    $2
}

XYZ="abc"
bashlike4 "local XYZ=def" myfnc
echo "parent: XYZ=$XYZ"
```

Here is the output of `/bin/sh <script>` and `/bin/bash --posix <script>`:

```
bashlike1: ...
myfnc: XYZ=myfdef
parent: XYZ=myfdef

bashlike2: ...
myfnc: XYZ=myfdef
parent: XYZ=abc

bashlike3: ...
myfnc: XYZ=myfdef
parent: XYZ=abc

bashlike4: ...
myfnc: XYZ=myfdef
parent: XYZ=abc
```

However, `/bin/bash <script>` and `/bin/dash <script>` produce:

```
bashlike1: ...
myfnc: XYZ=myfdef
parent: XYZ=abc

bashlike2: ...
myfnc: XYZ=myfdef
parent: XYZ=abc

bashlike3: ...
myfnc: XYZ=myfdef
parent: XYZ=abc

bashlike4: ...
myfnc: XYZ=myfdef
parent: XYZ=abc
```

And `/bin/zsh <script>` produces:

```
bashlike1: ...
myfnc: XYZ=myfdef
parent: XYZ=

bashlike2: ...
myfnc: XYZ=myfdef
parent: XYZ=abc

bashlike3: ...
myfnc: XYZ=myfdef
parent: XYZ=abc

bashlike4: ...
myfnc: XYZ=myfabc
parent: XYZ=myfabc
```

So, `bashlike2` and `bashlike3` produce the consistent results across the board. But, `bashlike1` [that tries to match the original question syntax most closely], has the widest variation.

And, `zsh` doesn't like `bashlike4` at all. That's too bad because it would have allowed:

```
bashlike4 "local X=3 ; local Y=4 ; local Z=5" ...
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

The first update was just for builtin/function, so it wouldn't work [wasn't intended to work] for external programs.

*Caveat:* Without having your full usage, this is a bit of guesswork.

I run fedora so I can't say whether this is true, but ubuntu may install `bash` in parallel to `dash`. In that case, using `#!/bin/bash -` (vs `#!/bin/sh -`) may be the simple solution. However, I'm going to assume that's not feasible.

The next choice would be:

```
RUNBIN="env XYZ=abc external_program"
eval $RUNBIN
```

I assume `external_program` is somewhat complex, involving some variables, or the `eval` wouldn't be necessary. If `XYZ=abc` were more complex as well, this might involve escaping `$`, etc. as I believe you've mentioned. So, maybe not an option either.

The underlying issue seems to be that when you set/export `XYZ` for one program, you do *not* want it to linger in the top/parent environment [or it will change the parent's value of `XYZ` which will be used later].

Because the `XYZ=abc eval $RUNBIN` syntax is inconsistent/unpredictable across various shells, we may have to [no matter how convenient it may be] discard it in favor of something that is a bit more "retro" but will always work:

```
# (1) simple export -- parent gets XYZ
export XYZ=abc
eval $RUNBIN

# (2) export then unset -- parent temporarily gets XYZ
export XYZ=abc
eval $RUNBIN
unset XYZ

# (3) preserve, export, restore -- parent's original is preserved
SAVE_XYZ=$XYZ
export XYZ=abc
eval $RUNBIN
unset XYZ
XYZ=$SAVE_XYZ
unset SAVE_XYZ

# (4) similar to (3), but we've created some helper functions to streamline
preserve XYZ=abc QRM=jkl
eval $RUNBIN
restore XYZ QRM
```

Another equally [or more so] retro method would be to *dynamically* build up a temporary wrapper script. The first N lines are `export SYM=val` followed by the final target invocation:

```
export XYZ=abc
export QRM=jkl
external_program $*
```

Then, invoke it via:

```
RUNBIN="wrapper ..."
eval $RUNBIN
```

If we generalize the wrapper script approach, we can dump out whatever variables into the file. Then, replace `eval $RUNBIN` with `echo $RUNBIN >> wrapper`. Now, `eval` is no longer required as this `echo` will give the same effect, more or less. This is how it was done before `eval` ever existed, sometimes by using an `awk` script to generate the wrapper script.

What we've dealing with is what I call "shell fragmentation" [ala "android fragmentation"]. On a given system, we don't really know what flavor of `*sh` has been installed as `/bin/sh` or if a given flavor is installed at all [under its secondary name].

However, on a given system other tools are *not* fragmented. `tcsh`, `perl`, `python`, and [yikes] `perl6` are all consistent. If installed, we can assume that virtually all things run the same. In `perl`, for newer features, there is a version number the script can check.

I wrote shell scripts for many years until I realized that `perl` could replace any combination of shell, sed, awk, etc. and do so more cleanly. So, for my personal stuff, it's 100% `perl`

Probably not an option for you, but I would have felt remiss if I didn't mention it.

Comment: Excellent: I guessed part of the answer would boil down to "*POSIX chose the definition that leads to a simpler implementation*" and I can see how the POSIX rule makes a shell a little simpler to code. // The problem with using env to set up the environment for running a command is that the command can't be a built-in like eval.  Putting eval around the env call means you have to worry about escaping the variable assignments properly.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is getting the assignments into the environment of an executable that I am having to run using a command like `eval $RUNBIN`. If you add `env | ( grep XYZ || echo XYZ not in the environment )`
to the end of your function `myfnc`, I think you'll find the assignments aren't always getting into the environment with shells other than `bash`.