# get the date part from filname from a path in shell script

Tags: string, bash, shell, filenames, filepath

I have a script as follows

```
pathtofile="/c/github/something/r1.1./myapp/*.txt"
echo $pathtofile
filename = ${pathtofile##*/}
echo $filename
```

i always have only one txt file as 2015-08-07.txt in the ../myapp/ directory. So the o/p is as follows:

```
/c/github/something/r1.1./myapp/2015-08-07.txt
*.txt
```

I need to extract the filename as 2015-08-07. i did follow a lot of the stack-overflow answers with same requirements. whats the best approach and how to do this to get the only date part of the filename from that path ?
FYI: the filename changes every time the script executed with today's date.

Comment: `filename = ${pathtofile##*/}` is wrong, you cannot have spaces around `=`. Also related: [Extract filename and extension in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/1983854)

Comment: Also, what is the format of the filename? Is it always <date>.txt or something else?

Comment: @fedorqui yes it is.. always

Comment: Then the suggested duplicate will help you do this. Let us know if it is not the case.

Comment: nope.. its not i spent lot on this!! its not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are saying:

```
pathtofile="/c/github/something/r1.1./myapp/*.txt"
```

you are storing the literal `/c/github/something/r1.1./myapp/*.txt` in a variable.

When you `echo`, this `*` gets expanded, so you see the results properly.

```
$ echo $pathtofile
/c/github/something/r1.1./myapp/2015-08-07.txt
```

However, if you quoted it you would see how the content is indeed a `*`:

```
$ echo "$pathtofile"
/c/github/something/r1.1./myapp/*.txt
```

So what you need to do is to store the value in, say, an array:

```
files=( /c/github/something/r1.1./myapp/*.txt )
```

This `files` array will be populated with the expansion of this expression.

Then, since you know that the array just contains an element, you can print it with:

```
$ echo "${files[0]}"
/c/github/something/r1.1./myapp/2015-08-07.txt
```

and then get the name by using [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/1983854):

```
$ filename=$(basename "${files[0]}")
$ echo "${filename%.*}"
2015-08-07
```

Comment: Yes .. It worked!! But basename dont work in my windows.. i went back to the previous method using { filename##*/ } to get the filename..

Comment: @flute good to read this. If you don't have `basename` it is good to use `filename="${fullfile##*/}"` as the linked question mentions and you are already using.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a lot for just getting the filename

```
$ find /c/github/something/r1.1./myapp/ -type f -printf "%f\n" | sed 's/\.txt//g'
2015-08-07
```

Comment: i tried this shows some syntax error.. fedorqui's method worked for me!!