# Need code for shell script for adding date and time stamp to filename

Tags: shell

I have a requirement to insert date and timestamp to file name

Example: 
If input filename is  `abc.xyz.123.txt`, then output should be like :

```
abc.xyz.123.yyyyddmmhhssmm.txt
```

It has to find the last place where . occurs in filename and insert date and timestamp at that place.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
basename=`basename "$fullfile"`
extension="${basename##*.}"
now=`date +"%Y%d%m"`
replacement="$now.$extension"
file=${fullfile/$extension/$replacement}
```

Also take a look at `man date` how to format the date output.
You can write data to your file like so:

```
echo "file contents" > "$file"
```

Edit/Update: I've read over the "last . occurence" - part. Sorry, I changed the code above to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
outputfilename=${filename%.*}$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).${filename##*.}
```

See also: [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

```
f=abc.xyz.123.txt
extension="${f##*.}"
filename="${f%.*}"
dt=`date +%Y%d%m%H%M%S`
echo "$filename.$dt.$extension"
```