# Extract substring after a character

Tags: linux, unix, sed, substring, cut

I'm trying to extract substring after the last period (dot).
examples below.

- `echo "filename..txt"`  should return "txt"
- `echo "filename.txt."`  should return ""
- `echo "filename"`       should return ""
- `echo "filename.xml"`   should return "xml"

I tried below. but works only if the character(dot) exists once. But my filename may have (dot) for 0 or more times.

```
echo "filename.txt" | cut -d "." -f2
```

Comment: So you want the file extension? You're using bash? Nothing easier than [Extract filename and extension in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash). (this wouldn't cover the `"filename" -> ""` case).

Answer (score 5):

Let's use `awk`!

```
awk -F"." '{print (NF>1)? $NF : ""}' file
```

This sets field separator to `.` and prints the last one. But if there is none, it prints an empty string.

#### Test

```
$ cat file
filename..txt
filename.txt.
filename
filename.xml
$ awk -F"." '{print (NF>1)? $NF : ""}' file
txt


xml
```

Answer (score 2):

One can make this portable (so it's not Linux-only), avoiding an ERE dependency, with the following:

```
$ sed -ne 's/.*\.//p' <<< "file..txt"
txt
$ sed -ne 's/.*\.//p' <<< "file.txt."

$ sed -ne 's/.*\.//p' <<< "file"
$ sed -ne 's/.*\.//p' <<< "file.xml"
xml
```

Note that for testing purposes, I'm using a "here-string" in bash. If your shell is not bash, use whatever your shell uses to feed data to sed.

The important bit here is the use of sed's `-n` option, which tells it not to print anything by default, combined with the **s**ubstitute command's explicit `p` flag, which tells sed to print *only* upon a successful substitution, which obviously requires a dot to be included in the pattern.

With this solution, the difference between `"file.txt."` and `"file"` is that the former returns the input line replaced with null (so you may still get a newline depending on your usage), whereas the latter returns nothing, as `sed` is not instructed to print, as no `.` is included in the input.  The end result may well be the same, of course:

```
$ printf "#%s#\n" $(sed -ne 's/.*\.//p' <<< "file.txt.")
##
$ printf "#%s#\n" $(sed -ne 's/.*\.//p' <<< "file")
##
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple to do with awk:

```
awk -F"." '{ print $NF }'
```

What this does: With dot as a delimiter, extract the last field from the input.

Comment: Fails the no-extension case. But that's easily fixable by adding `/\./` (if empty output, no blank line, is acceptable and with `/\./{print $NF;next} {print ""}` otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

Use sed in 2 steps: first remove string without a dot and than remove up to the last dot:

```
sed -e 's/^[^.]*$//' -e 's/.*\.//'
```

Test:

```
for s in file.txt.. file.txt. file.txt filename file.xml; do
   echo "$s -> $(echo "$s" | sed -e 's/^[^.]*$//' -e 's/.*\.//')"
done
```

Testresult:

```
file.txt.. ->
file.txt. ->
file.txt -> txt
filename ->
file.xml -> xml
```

Actually the answer of @ghoti is roughly the same, just a bit shorter (better). 
This solution can be used by other readers who wants to do something like this in another language.