# Copy if different and rename as date and timestamp

Tags: linux, bash, shell

So I have a file that I want to copy if it has been modified. I want to save it as date and time in it's new location.

```
mv my_file.db $(date +%F)
```

This command will move it and set the date as the name, but it removes the extension. I have 3 different file extensions I want to move. I also want to have the timestamp as I will be copying multiple times per day.

Input:

```
sdfgdg.a
abdfgs.b
dfgdfg.c
```

So by running...

```
mv * ../Folder
```

Should produce:

```
Folder/sdfgdg-2015-01-02-14:50:00.a
Folder/abdfgs-2015-01-02-14:50:00.b
Folder/dfgdfg-2015-01-02-14:50:00.c
```

Comment: `mv foo.db $(date +%F).db`? if you want to preserve the extension, you have to include it in the target filename...

Comment: @MarcB I thought of that but the extensions change and are not known. You're also missing the time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash

Comment: @MarcB and what about the time?

Comment: you get out of `date` what you tell it to provide, since your example only had %F, that's what I used as well. if you want a different format, then tell `date` about it...

Comment: Please add your desired filename to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus added to the question

Comment: Do you want to use the current time or the file's modified time?

Comment: @glennjackman current time is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this function to your ~/.bashrc and source it (`source ~/.bashrc`) or login with a second session.

```
function mymv() {
  if [[ $# -lt 2 ]]; then
     echo "Syntax error: missing aruments"
     return 1
  fi

  target="${@: -1}"     # last argument
  d="$(date +%F-%T)"

  while [[ $# -ge 2 ]]; do
    file="$1"
    mv -v "$file" "$target/${file%.*}-$d.${file##*.}"
    shift
  done
}
```

Usage:

```
mymv file ... directory
```

Example:

```
mymv * ../Folder
```