# Retrieve only file name into a table in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to retrieve the filename.txt from a linux path and insert filename into a table column in hive.
Is it possible to retrieve only file name from a path and insert it into a hive table using virtual columns? please advice!

e.g. of path /home/usr/path/filename.txt and insert filename into a table.
create table t( name string);

Thanks!

Comment: from where you need to get filename? add more info: filename with path (as an example)

Comment: Example of input path and desired column content please

Comment: Have added the info. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash

Comment: Do not understand your scenario completely. If you just want to extract filename from full path, please see my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks! can you please let me know how to insert file name into hive table via shell scripting? I'm new to linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to run against HDFS - command - `awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'` will you just file name.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/departments|awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'|egrep -v 'Found|_SUCCESS'
part-m-00000
part-m-00001
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

if you want to run against local file system then - command - `ls -1` will give you file name. you can also use `awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'`

you can create shell script as: (uncomment `hive` statements)

```
#!/bin/sh

files=`hadoop fs -ls /user/cloudera/departments|awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'|egrep -v 'Found|_SUCCESS'`

for file in $files
 do
   #hive -e "insert into table t(name) values (\"$file\");"
   echo "insert into table t(name) values (\"$file\");"
done
```

should instert in hive table:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ./test.sh 
insert into table t(name) values ("part-m-00000");
insert into table t(name) values ("part-m-00001");
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you have a full file name in variable $filename:

```
 #!/bin/bash
        filename=$(basename "$fullfile")

        #pass variable to the hive script:
        hive -hiveconf filename=$filename -f your_script_name.hql
```

Inside the script:

```
        insert into your_table
        select some columns,  '${hiveconf:filename}' as filename  --use variable
        from some table... ;
        or just insert values...
```

Or just simply do:

```
hive -e "insert into t values '$filename'"
```