# How to get the full name of a folder if I only know the beginning

Tags: shell, unix

I am receiving an input from the user which looks like follows:

```
echo +++Your input:+++
read USER_INPUT
```

The way I should use it is to retrieve the full name of a folder which *starts* with that input, but that contains other stuffs right after. All I know is that the folder is unique.

For example:

**User input**

```
123456
```

**Target folder**

```
/somepath/someotherpath/123456-111-222
```

**What I need**

```
MYNEED=123456-111-222
```

I was thinking to retrieve this with an `MYNEED=$(ls /somepath/someotherpath/$USER_INPUT*)`, but if I do this I will get instead all the content of `/somepath/someotherpath/123456-111-222` because that's the only folder existing with that name so the `ls` command directly goes to the next step.

May I have your idea to retrieve the value `123456-111-222` into a variable that I will need to use after?

Comment: If you really need the name of the directory, you can do the full directory listing and search for it, if it is unique. But if all you want to do is to cd into that directory, you can simply type:

Comment: I'm sorry, I left my edit too long and I couldn't save it. Here is the rest of what I was writing:

    $ cd 123456*

If there is only one directory beginning with "123456", the cd command will figure out which directory to go into.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract filename and extension in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`basename` extracts the filename from the whole path so this will do it:

```
MYNEED=$(basename /somepath/someotherpath/123456*)
```

Comment: any comment on the downvote? Is this not what the OP wanted?

Comment: It is exactly what I needed, not sure why you got a downvote but you definitely got my upvote.