# Redirect output No such file or directory

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to launch a script to echo (as a test) the file name of files in a different directory but get the "No such file or directory" error. It looks like it is appending the whole directory of where I'm echoing from to the file name I'm trying to redirect to but how do I fix that. Thank you.

```
for filename in /data/logs/2017/jan/201701*
do
echo $filename > /home/bishopm/${filename%.gz}
done
```

Getting the following errors for each file trying to echo:

```
./data_collector.sh: line 5: /home/bishopm//data/logs/2017/jan/20170131: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the target path you want to use? `/home/bishopm/`  or other?

Comment: You need [Extract filename and extension in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/1983854)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to tell sh that you want to iterate through the list of files in that directory, so you call the `ls` command

```
for filename in $(ls /data/logs/2017/jan/201701*);
do
file=$(basename $filename)
echo $file > /home/bishopm/${file%.gz}
done
```

Edit: now it should work, provided that the bishopm directory exists
Edit2: substituted the `rev | cut | rev` chain with `basename`, thanks to Sild

Comment: `sh` expands the `*` already so in fact, you don't need to ls the files

Comment: yes but the resulting $filename will have the full path, instead of the output of ls that would only be the name of the file. Also the forward slash problem does not happen in this way

Comment: It still does the appending instead of only redirecting just the file name.

Comment: Only now I got what the problem was. Check if the edit fixes it for you

Comment: Thanks PMonti! That did it.

Comment: please use ```basename``` instead of ```rev|cut|rev```. It's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 `/` in your path: `/home/bishopm//...`.  Try:

```
...
echo $filename > "/home/bishopm${filename%.gz}"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

More elegant POSIX solution:

```
for filpath in /data/logs/2017/jan/201701*; do
    filename="$(basename "${filepath}")"
    echo "${filename}" > /home/bishopm/${filename%.gz}
done
```