# Get extension of files in Bash

Tags: string, bash, filenames

I am writing a script which will sort files by extensions. I know a method to do this by file's names. The problem is, that same files haven't got extension in their names. For example if I have file: `file.txt` there is no problem to get an extension by simple `extension="${filename##*.}"`. But if file name is just `filename` this method doesn't work. Is there any other option to get extension of file and put it to variable in Bash script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are only asking how to put the file extension of a filename into a variable in bash, and you are not asking about the sorting part.
To do so, the following brief script can print the extension of each file from a file list.

```
#!/bin/sh
filesInCurrentDir=`ls`
for file in $filesInCurrentDir; do
    extention=`sed 's/^\w\+.//' <<< "$file"`
    echo "the extention for $file is: "$extention #for debugging
done
```

the variable that contains the extention of the current file analysed is called `extention`. The command `sed 's/^\w\+.//` matched any length of characters until the first dot found in the filename and then removes it. Therefore if there are multiple file extentions these would be all listed (e.g. `file.txt` -> get extention `txt` but `file.odt.pdf` -> get extention `odt.pdf`).

## EXAMPLE

Current Folder content (this can be any space-separated list of files that you feed to the loop)

```
aaab.png
abra
anme2.jpg
cadabra
file
file.png
file.txt
loacker.png
myText
name.pdf
rusty.jgp
```

Result of script above:

```
the extention of aaab.png is: png
the extention of abra is: 
the extention of anme2.jpg is: jpg
the extention of cadabra is: 
the extention of file is: 
the extention of file.png is: png
the extention of file.txt is: txt
the extention of loacker.png is: png
the extention of myText is: 
the extention of name.pdf is: pdf
the extention of rusty.jgp is: jgp
```

In this way, files with no extension will result in the extension variable being empty.

Comment: for who downvotes: if you can explain me what's wrong I can review my answer.

Comment: Though i have not down vote you, i need to tell you that your solution breaks easily. Just run `touch "file spaced.txt"` and test your code. Moreover google around why you should not parse the output of `ls` and how to loop in files with for and globing (i.e `for file in *`) - Another gray point is the use of sed when bash is equipped with parameter expansion that can bring you the required results. Is like using a machine gun in luna park to win the teddy bear. Moreover not all `sed` versions work the same .

Answer (score 12):

You can get the base name of the file by *removing* the extension, then removing *that* from the original.

```
base=${filename%.*}
ext=${filename#$base.}
```

I like the `case` statement more, though; the intent is clearer.

Comment: This code actually returns $filename if there is no extension.  By adding another step, you can make it return "" if there is no extension. 
`extension_echo () { file=$1; base=${file%.*}; ext=${file#$base}; ext=${ext#.}; echo "$ext";}`

Answer (score 10):

Without bashisms like `[[`:

```sh
case $filename in
  (.*.*) extension=${filename##*.};;
  (.*)   extension="";;
  (*.*)  extension=${filename##*.};;
  (*)    extension="";;
esac
```

Works in any Bourne-heritage shell.

Answer (score 6):

```
filename="file.txt"
ext="${filename##*.}"
if [[ "$ext" != "$filename" ]]; then echo "$ext"; else echo "no extension"; fi
```

Output:

```
txt
```

---

```
filename="file"
ext="${filename##*.}"
if [[ "$ext" != "$filename" ]]; then echo "$ext"; else echo "no extension"; fi
```

Output:

```
no extension
```

Comment: But the problem is, that these files without extensions in names are for example txt or jpg files and I should put them to the proper folder.

Answer (score 2):

For a situation like:

```
$ ls file*
file1  file1.txt  file2
```

You can do something like:

```
$ ls file* |awk -F. '{print (NF>1?$NF:"no extension")}'
no extension
txt
no extension
```