# How to obtain the absolut path of the copy when copying files?

Tags: bash

I'm copying like this:

```
cp "$input_file_absolut_path" "$output_directory_absolut_path"
```

Now I want to do something with the copied file, but i CAN'T just:

```
copy_absolut_path="$output_directory_absolut_path/$input_file_absolut_path"
```

Any tip to obtain the absolut path of the copied file?

Comment: New Stackoverflow users should be forced to read all posts with more than 1000 upvotes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/965072/402322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to use the `$input_file_absolut_path`. But since you copied only the file, not the whole directory structure into `$output_directory_absolut_path`, you have to do it like this:

```
copy_absolut_path="$output_directory_absolut_path/$(basename $input_file_absolut_path)"
```

`basename` will get you just the filename without the directory structure. Then you concatenate it with the output_directory_absolut_path.

Comment: Thank you for the early response, this solved my problem.

Comment: What if `$output_directory_absolute_path` already has a trailing `/`?

Comment: @ShammelLee When you have a path with multiple slashes, this gets ignored. Do a simple `cd whatever//path` with double slashes somewhere and you will get to your desired location. There's no need for super fancy solutions that are harder to read.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if your filename doesn't contain slash, you can concatenate `$output_directory_absolut_path` and `basename "$input_file_absolut_path"`

Comment: Thank you for the early response, i tried your previous one but i didnt make it work (newbie here).basename solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```
copy_absolute_path="$(cd "$output_directory_absolute_path"; pwd)/${input_file_absolute_path##*/}"
```

## Explanation

If `output_directory_absolute_path` ends with a `/`, then `$(cd "$output_directory_absolute_path"; pwd)` will return the path without the trailing `/`.

`$(input_file_absolute_path##*/}` returns everything after the last `/`.