# bash script to handle multiple files at once

Tags: bash, shell, loops

I have files with multiple extension in a folder like .txt, .update, .text. The file names are like

out1.txt,
out1.text,
out1.update,

out2.txt,
out2.text,
out2.update

and so on....My command looks like this:

```
./script.pl out1.txt out1.text out1.update
```

I would like to put this command in the loop for every file. I have tried to use a loop like:

```
for i in *.{txt,text,update}
```

But it takes the full name including the extension so I couldn't figure out how to deduce the specific extension files in the command.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Comment: I checked it but it is something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use :

```
for f in *.txt;
do
    b=${f%.txt} # the trick is there
    ./script.pl $b.txt $b.text $b.update
done
```

Comment: It gives an error that  "b" command is not found. I have through multiple testings but it is giving an error.

Comment: It worked. I had the space in between variable "b" and equal sign "=". I remove it and then it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @AsmaTahir, indeed, bash is sensitive to the space before and after "="; I fixed my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the space later that's why I removed it. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

```
ext=$(awk -F\. '{ print "."$NF }' <<< $i)
fil=$(basename -s $ext $i)
```

use awk to extract the extension (second delimited piece of data using ".")
Use basename -s with the extension to the get the filename without the extension