# Extract positional filename and extension in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to create a script that renames a file that has 2 extensions by deleting the midle extension. In reference to this, I found this great thread:
[Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Someone posted there this in regards to shell parameter extension:

```
~% FILE="example.tar.gz"
~% echo "${FILE%%.*}"
example
~% echo "${FILE%.*}"
example.tar
~% echo "${FILE#*.}"
tar.gz
~% echo "${FILE##*.}"
gz
```

My question is on the above statement: how do you echo **example.gz** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it on one operation; you need to use temporary variables.

```
$ ext=${FILE##*.} # ext=gz
$ tmp=${FILE%.*}  # Remove .gz
$ echo "${tmp%.*}.$ext"  # Remove .tar, then add .gz back
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve it without any temporary variable, by combining the correct statements that gives the 2 parts you need with a `.`in between :

```
echo "${FILE%%.*}.${FILE##*.}"
```