# How to rename without remove the extionsion dot of a file name

Tags: bash, rename

In order to rename music samples with .wav and .flac extensions I use this line:

```
for f in * ; do rename 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9:0:4]//g' "$f" ;done
```

But what happen is, when the name of the file is like this:

```
name * of ( the f?ile.wav
```

it becomes:

```
nameofthefilewav
```

it shold be:

```
nameofthefile.wav
```

What do I need to get the extension dot on his place?

Comment: Just replacing the extension? Maybe `rename 's/.wav$/.flac/' *.wav` ?

Comment: You are trying to replace anything that is not inside `[..]` by doing `[^a-zA-Z0-9:0:4]`, but you've missed the `.`

Comment: Why are the there `[` and `]` part of filenames? Was it suggest an example? If not remove that

Comment: @ReutSharabani  for f in * ; do rename 's/.wav$/.flac/' *.wav "$f" ;done that by that I have to take care of what the extension is - cq otherwise it will change all the wav into flac - it works but it not what I want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `basename` and parameter expansion to get the filename and its extension.

```
filename=$(basename -- "$fullfile")
extension="${filename##*.}"
filename="${filename%.*}"
```

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

***EDIT:***

```
bash-4.1$ ls
1.mp3  2.mp3  3.mp3
bash-4.1$ for f in `ls`; do
filename=$(basename -- "$f")
extension="${filename##*.}"
filename="${filename%.*}"
echo "FROM: $filename.$extension TO: $filename.wav"
done
FROM: 1.mp3 TO: 1.wav
FROM: 2.mp3 TO: 2.wav
FROM: 3.mp3 TO: 3.wav
```

Comment: I do not understand how to use this? I tried this with a echo on $filename but it don't print anything

Comment: - for f in * ; do rename 's/ //' *.wav "$f" ;done - this is the same as what you have. It only removes the spaces. I would like to remove also unwanted characters like  * ; ( & ) e.t.c  - I don't wont change extension.

Comment: this changes the extension, but in my case there is no extension left by that the dot before the extension is removed.

Comment: Do the rename only on $filename and then concatenate it back with "\.$extension"

Comment: Yes I think also that is possible solution, thanks for thinking with me - aldo I think it must be easy to replace a dot for the extension - i know it in Python.  I will vote your answer, not really what I wont, but so far there is nothing else.