# Batch script that replaces static string in file with filename

Tags: batch-file, filenames, text-processing

I have 3000 files in `c:\data\`, and I need to replace a static string in each of them with the name of the file. For example, in the file `12345678.txt` there will be some records along with the string `99999999`, and I want to replace `99999999` with the filename `12345678`.

How can I do this using a batch script?

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
replace_string="99999999"
for f in *.txt; do
    sed -i "s/${replace_string}/${f%.*}/g" "$f";
done
```

**Explanation:**

- `for f in *.txt; do ... done`: Loop through files named `*.txt` in current directory.
- `sed -i ... file` Edit `file` *in place* (`-i`).
- `"s/pattern/replacement/g"` Substitutes (`s`) *pattern* with *replacement* globally (`g`).
- `${f%.*}` Filename without extension ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash))

Comment: GNU `sed` would make the edits "permanent" with the `-i` flag; otherwise, the converted contents are sent to stdout.

Comment: It was unclear originally, but the question is on Windows and the solution needs to be a batch script

Answer (score 0):

With GNU tools:

```
find . -regex '.*/[0-9]+\.txt' -type f -exec gawk -i inplace '
  BEGINFILE {f = FILENAME; sub(".*/", "", f); sub(/\..*/, "", f)}
  {gsub(/\<99999999\>/, f); print}' {} +
```

Comment: It was unclear originally, but the question is on Windows and the solution needs to be a batch script