# Replacing a String In Multiple Files With Their Filename

Tags: powershell, cmd

So I have a whole large folder of text files where I'd like to change the string **unamed** in each one of them to the name of the file itself, extension excluded.

So far with my scavengous skills I have come up with the following, but it doesn't give what I'm looking for as it changes the name to every single collected file

```
$path = "*.txt"
$filename = Get-Item $path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
$Change = Get-Content $path
$Change | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "unamed", $filename} | Set-Content $path
```

So basically something like this

> The name of this file is unamed.

is becoming

> The name of this file is File1Name File2Name File3Name.

There is also a side issue I'm experiencing where the results of the all the files merges into one file (so contents of file 1 will now also contain contents of all the other files too). How can I get the results I seek oh wise ones?

If there is a way to settle this with regular command line instead of powershell then I'll settle for that too (I found this but had issue with replace_string being invalid command? [Batch script that replaces static string in file with filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52101137/batch-script-that-replaces-static-string-in-file-with-filename))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt" | ForEach-Object {
  $Path=$_.FullName; (Get-Content $Path) -replace 'unamed', $_.BaseName | Set-Content $Path 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Esperanto's answer works well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52574814/45375) and is PSv2-compatible; here's a much faster - but more memory-intensive - PSv3+ solution:

```
Get-Content -Raw *.txt | ForEach-Object {
  $_ -replace 'unamed', [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.PSPath) |
    Set-Content $_.PSPath
}
```

- Unless you have special file-matching needs such as looking for files *recursively* or needing to exclude files or needing to match by file attributes, you don't need `Get-Item` / `Get-ChildItem` to enumerate files of interest - you can pass a wildcard pattern such as `*.txt` directly to `Get-Content`'s (implied) `-Path` parameter.
- `Get-Content -Raw` (PSv3+) reads the the entire content of each file matching `*.txt` into memory *as a whole*, as a *single string*.

  - Note: Because each file is read as a whole before it is output to the pipeline, this solution may not work with very large files, depending on available memory.
- `Get-Content` decorates the strings it outputs with information about the where the string came from, so that the `.PSPath` property on each string returned contains the full filename of the file the string was read from.
- `[IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.PSPath)` extracts the filename root from the path (the mere filename without extension)

  - The direct use of .NET is necessary, unfortunately, the `Split-Path` cmdlet doesn't allow you to do this in Windows PowerShell, but in PowerShell *Core* you could use `Split-Path -LeafBase` instead.

**Caveat**: `Set-Content` uses a *default* encoding (Windows PowerShell: "ANSI"; PowerShell *Core*: UTF-8 without BOM), which may or may not be the same as the input encoding; use the `-Encoding` parameter as needed.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$filename = Get-Item $path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName`

`$filename` now contains an *array* of filename roots (base names).

> `$Change = Get-Content $path`

`$Change` now contains a *single array* whose elements are the lines *from all input files*.

> `$Change | ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace "unamed", $filename} | Set-Content $path`

- Because `$Change` is a single, flat array, you've lost the partitioning of the array elements into the files or origin, and `Set-Content` sends *all* lines to the target file(s).
- Because `$filename` is an *array* whereas the 2nd RHS operand of `-replace` only supports a *scalar* (single string), `$_ -replace "unamed", $filename` causes `$filename` to be converted to a single string, which is a space-separated *concatenation* of the array elements (filename roots).
- `Set-Content $Path` so happens to write the flat (modified) array of lines to *multiple* files, namely those existing files that match the wildcard expression in `$Path`, `*.txt`:

  - As stated, the input `Set-Content` receives is a *concatenation* of the input files' lines, so all output files receive the concatenated (modified) content from *all* input files (all files whose names match wildcard pattern `*.txt`)
  - As an aside: That `Set-Content *.txt` allows writing the *same* content to *multiple* preexisting output files is a surprising and possibly destructive feature and should arguably not be supported - see [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6729).

Comment: @Xir: my pleasure; hope it helped.