# How to expand to current remote path in custom command prompt in WinSCP?

Tags: winscp

I tried to make a custom command that unzip a selected file to a path defined by user, but with a default value to current path and current archive name in remote server using this command, but the prompt just gave me an empty value. What's the mistake?

```
unzip "!" -d "!?&Extraction Path:?!/!!"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. There's actually a feature request for this functionality:
[Bug 743 – Allow patterns in default prompt answer in custom commands](https://winscp.net/tracker/743).

Though even that it meant to support only static (non-file) patterns like `!/`, but not file patterns like `!`.

---

If it helps, in [WinSCP extensions](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension), it's possible to use non-file patterns, like `!/` (but not file patterns, like `!`) in default [prompt/option](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/extension#options) answer.

The extension file may look like:

```
@name     Unzip...
@side     Remote
@command  unzip "!" -d "%ExtractionPath%"
@option   ExtractionPath -run textbox "Extraction path:" "!/"
```

Just store the above script to a text file and [install it to WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_commands#extensions).

---

Another thing that you can do, is to add a checkbox that will make WinSCP add an archive name (without an extension) to the path, with some clever use of shell (bash) constructs. This way, you can uncheck the checkbox and add a custom subfolder to the target path manually, if you do not want to use the archive name for the subfolder name.

```
@name     Unzip...
@side     Remote
@command  unzip "!" -d "%ExtractionPath%`[[ '%AddName%' = '1' ]] && AN=! && echo ${AN%.*}`"
@option   ExtractionPath -run textbox "Extraction path:" "!/"
@option   AddName -run checkbox "Add file name to the extraction path" "1" "1"
```

[image]

---

Yet another alternative is to use your own placeholder for archive name (e.g. `ARCHIVENAME`) that will get replaced by real name (without an extension), when the command is executed. Then, if you do not want to use the archive name for the subfolder name, you replace the `ARCHIVENAME` with a custom name.

```
@name     Unzip...
@side     Remote
@command  unzip "!" -d "`EP=%ExtractionPath%;AN=!;AN=${AN%.*};echo ${EP/ARCHIVENAME/$AN}`"
@option   ExtractionPath -run textbox "Extraction path:" "!/ARCHIVENAME"
```

[image]

Comment: That last method is genius! Thank you for the very thorough answer!

Comment: Hey I try to modify the last command a little bit to make it remove the file extension by using this command `@command  unzip "!" -d "``EP=%ExtractionPath%;echo $(${EP/ARCHIVENAME/!} | awk -F. '{ print $1 }')``"` and WinSCP hanged on executing command and give me an error saying `Host is not communicating...`, any idea why? PS: dont worry about the extra `` mark, it's the formatting which I don't know how to fix yet.

Comment: Ah okay, let's say I have an archive named `archive.zip`, using the command in last method would failed since `unzip` can't extract to the same path that contains the same name of archive, for example, extracting  `/home/martin/archive.zip` to `/home/martin/archive.zip` (even though it's the folder name) would failed. And yeah you're right that it would modify the custom name, which I'll try to solve it after.

Comment: That works perfectly now! Btw I nerver see one uses `${AN%.*}` before (and it looks shorter and more efficient than `sed` or `awk`, would you mind explain what the specifier did?

Comment: I took it from here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/965053/850848#965072 - Explained here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html (though I cannot really say, I understand it fully).