# Run command on pair of files (different file types) with matching character string

Tags: bash, cat, seq, gnu-parallel

I have a list of files:

```
catfish.fa
polar.fa
catfish.ids.txt
polar.ids.txt
```

I want to run this command for each file with a matching character string. So for example, I'd like to run this:

`cat catfish.fa | seqkit grep -f catfish.ids.txt > catfish.output.fa`

Similarly...

`cat polar.fa | seqkit grep -f polar.ids.txt > polar.output.fa`

How can I run this command for each file pair in the directory and in parallel? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run one job per CPU core in parallel:

```
parallel 'cat {} | seqkit grep -f {.}.ids.txt > {.}.output.fa' ::: *fa
```

May I suggest you run with `--dry-run` first, so you can see what will be run?

```
parallel --dry-run 'cat {} | seqkit grep -f {.}.ids.txt > {.}.output.fa' ::: *fa
```

Also consider spending 20 minutes on reading chapter 1+2 of the book GNU Parallel 2018 (print: http://www.lulu.com/shop/ole-tange/gnu-parallel-2018/paperback/product-23558902.html online: https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014). Your command line will love you for it.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent resource. When I tried this the terminal just returned a ">". I am using macOS and the parallel command is installed.

Comment: End ' was missing. Fixed.

Comment: Yep I kept looking at it and was like oh it was missing an '. Thank you for help and your book is excellent. I will spend time learning it.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.fa
do
   filename="${f%.*}"
   if [ -e ${f}.ids.txt ]
   then
      cat ${f}.fa  | seqkit grep -f ${f}.ids.txt >${f}.output.fa
   fi
done
```

`filename="${f%.*}"` extracts the filename without extension, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash) for an explanation.
The purpose of the `if` is to single out only the files ending with `.fa` which have a corresponding `.ids.txt` file.
If you want everything to be run in parallel on each pair, append a `&` at the end of the `cat ${f}.fa ...` file. (Beware to not generate too many parallel tasks!)

Answer (score 1):

With bash's [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
for file in *.fa; do seqkit grep -f "${file%%.*}.id.txt" >"${file%%.*}.output.fa" <"$file" & done
```