# How to use magic bytes to identify files using python

Tags: python, file, byte

I was given a problem that stated:

> We've extracted one of the alien zip files, it's a bunch of PNG files, but we think only one of them is valid. Use magic byte to determine which it is.
>   Tip: Find and read the correct file to get the flag.

All the png files are stored in the /tmp directory. After a couple of attempts at the problem I have only gotten so far. My code runs fine but prints `no` for every file with none of them being the correct one according to my code.

Here's my code so far:

```
import glob,os

magic_numbers = {'.png': bytes([0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A])}
max_read_size = max(len(m) for m in magic_numbers.values()) # get max size of magic numbers of the dict
os.chdir("/tmp")
for x in glob.glob("*.png"):
    with open(x, 'rb') as fd:
            file_head = fd.read(max_read_size)

    if file_head.startswith(magic_numbers['.png']):
            print("It's a PNG File")
    else:
            print("no")
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong but I cannot figure out what it is. Is it a problem with the loop? How am I supposed use magic bytes to identify files?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/filemagic/

Comment: You code works for me. I created a `tmp` folder with a number of png files in it, plus a text file I created (which I renamed to .png) and your code correctly identified all the files. (I'm using python 3.7)

Comment: Hey buddy, it's probably too late for you... but the problem isn't the logic you've used here. You're expecting the question to be more sophisticated than it is. Just dump the headers and look at them.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @jtlz2 no it's not don't worry

Comment: Is this from CyberStart?

- from a fellow CyberStart participant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code needed a bit of tweaking, by prefixing the word `png` with a dot, you're making it seem as if the file has an extension.  Also, print `file_head`. Run this:

```
import glob, os

magic_numbers = {'png': bytes([0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A])}
max_read_size = max(len(m) for m in magic_numbers.values()) # get max size of magic numbers of the dict
os.chdir("/tmp")

for x in glob.glob("*png"):
    with open(x, 'rb') as fd:
        file_head = fd.read()
        print(file_head)

    if file_head.startswith(magic_numbers['png']):
        print("It's a PNG File")
    else:
        print("no")
```

It should print something like this:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x15\xc4\x89\x00\x00\x00\nIDATx\x9cc\x00\x01\x00\x00\x05\x00\x01\r\n-\xb4\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82The flag is: 2NECGNQM4GD3QPD' It's a PNG File
```

Your flag will probably be different from mine.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

you can use [python-magic](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/) library.

> python-magic is a Python interface to the libmagic file type identification library. libmagic identifies file types by checking their headers according to a predefined list of file types.(from pypi)

this library cheks alon the magic numbers to identifies the file type.

```
import magic
print(magic.from_file('file.png'))
```

and the out put is:

```
'PNG image data, 2480 x 3437, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced'
```

have fun!

EDIT: For windows use `pip install python-magic-bin`, Windows lacks DLL's, so you have to install it that way. This is specified in the [package's installation instructions](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic#windows).

Comment: does not work `ImportError: failed to find libmagic.  Check your installation`

Comment: @happy_marmoset try to use `pip install python-magic-bin` For Windows. Windows lacks DLL's, so you have to install it that way. This is specified in [the package's installation instructions](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic#windows).