# Bash Basename Modification

Tags: bash, filenames, creation

Inside of bash I am loading a file such as:

```
/path/to/dir/filename.ext
```

now the idea is to use that file name and "extend its' name" upon modification such as:

```
some operation /path/to/dir/filename.ext > path/to/dir/filename_extendingfilename.ext;
```

So far I have managed to call the filename using this from another question that has already been asked on here (for reference [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)) :

```
basename filename .extension

basename /path/to/dir/filename.txt .txt

filename
```

The issue im having is the creation of a new file which has the filename of the source file and extents on it using "_ *extension.ext*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bash` [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is an option here:

```sh
f=/path/to/dir/filename.ext
f2=${f%.ext*}"_extendingfilename.ext"
```

The shell parameter expansion cuts at the last occurrence of `.ext` (i.e. it will also work correctly for a file like `/path/to/dir/file.ext.name.ext`)

Here is an example for the redirection in the answer:

```sh
f=/path/to/dir/filename.ext
someoperation $f > ${f%.ext*}"_extendingfilename.ext"
```

Comment: does that work when im creating a new file thou ? as in    path/to/dir/filename_extendingfilename.ext   such as `f=/path/to/dir/filename.ext
f2=${f%.ext*}"_extendingfilename.ext"
echo $f2

some operation /path/to/dir/filename.ext > path/to/dir/echo $f + $f2.ext;`

Comment: added a one-liner as an example for your redirection of *some operation*.