# How to strip paths from file names on standard input

Tags: bash

How could I strip the paths from a list of file names on standard input? I basically need something like `basename` that iterates over **standard input**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read path; do basename "$path" ; done
```

Simple loop.

Comment: I turned that into a function that works perfectly. function basename_pipe() {
 while read path; do basename "$path" ; done
}

Answer (score 0):

Try `xargs basename -a`. It'll run faster than a simple loop as `basename` won't be run for each filename.

```
$ printf "%s\n" foo/bar bar/baz | xargs basename -a
bar
baz
```

Note that the above won't correctly handle filenames with spaces. You'll want to use the `-0` option to `xargs` and ensure the input is NUL terminated.

```
$ printf "%s\0" 'foo/foo bar' bar/baz | xargs -0 basename -a
foo bar
baz
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

If your filename is in the form of a variable such as `$fullpathname`

```
nopathfile="${fullpathname##*/}"
```

It's in the bash manpage at the section called "Parameter Expansion"