# Extract the file name of last slash from path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

I am finding the files in specific location now I need to extract the file name which is after last slash from that path without its extension like `*.war` by using shell scripting.

I tried below to find out the data in the path:

```
find /data1/jenkins_devops/builds/develop/5bab159c1c40cfc44930262d30511ac7337805fa -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*.war'
```

Ex.- This folder "5bab159c1c40cfc44930262d30511ac7337805fa" contains multiple .war file like `interview.war`, `auth.war` so I am expecting output is interview war.

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is stopping you?

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened?  Why didn't it work?  Why is this tagged groovy?

Comment: @tim_yates I tried with this- 
echo "find /data1/jenkins_devops/builds/develop/ab7f302d157d839b4ac3d7917cfa2d550ba2e73e/auth.war" | awk -F'/' '{print $6}'
but not getting the proper result.

Comment: @tim_yates Actually "ab7f302d157d839b4ac3d7917cfa2d550ba2e73e" is my folder name that contains multiple .war files and I need all the names to be printed of that war files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract filename and extension in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are much elegant ways to achieve the objectve. The following use `awk` to achieve the objectiv:

```
find /data1/jenkins_devops/builds/develop/5bab159c1c40cfc44930262d30511ac7337805fa -mindepth 1 -type f -name *.war | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' | awk -F "." '{print $1}'
```

Awk `NF` returns the number of fields and you can use that to print the last column. First you seperate the columns with `/` as field seperator in awk and use it to print last column. Then use `.` as seperator and print the first column to achieve the desired result. It is done in the above script.

Comment: actually I am finding the files from specific location mentioned below and need to print last filename without .war find /data1/jenkins_devops/builds/develop/5bab159c1c40cfc44930262d30511ac7337805fa -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*.war

Comment: @uday pipe them to the awk. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [basename](https://linux.die.net/man/1/basename):

```
the_path="/data1/jenkins_devops/builds/develop/ab7f302d157d839b4ac3d7917cfa2d550ba2e73e/auth.war"
basename "$the_path" .war
```

Comment: actually I am finding the files from specific location mentioned below and need to print last filename without .war
find /data1/jenkins_devops/builds/develop/5bab159c1c40cfc44930262d30511ac7337805fa -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*.war'

Comment: So? So pipe them to basename via a while read loop or by xargs.